# C++ specify array indexes in initializer, like C

Tags: c++, c

I used C before (embedded stuff), and I can initialize my arrays like that:

```
int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
```

i.e. I can specify indexes inside initializer.
Currently I'm learning `Qt/C++`, and I can't believe this isn't supported in C++.

I have this option: `-std=gnu++0x`, but anyway it isn't supported. (I don't know if it is supported in C++11, because Qt works buggy with gcc 4.7.x)

So, is it really not supported in C++? Or maybe there's a way to enable it?

**UPD:** currently I want to initialize const array, so `std::fill` won't work.

Comment: "Or maybe there's a way to enable it?" - use C? (:D) Good question, +1.

Comment: Your code is neither C (including C11). C11 does not support initializing ranges this way (`[a...b]=1`), only single elements (`[a]=1`).

Comment: hmm... can you use `extern "C" { ................ }` around declaration? But I believe this syntax is your embedded compiler's addition.

Comment: @ybungalobill, not C11, but C99 (if i haven't mixed up anything)

Comment: @anishsane "I believe this syntax is your embedded compiler's addition" - no, it's a GNU extension to C99.

Comment: Nor C99. ...more characters.

Comment: @ybungalobill Again, this is a GNU extension.

Comment: @H2CO3: I know, but the OP calls its "C" and then wanders why it is not in C++...\

Comment: [The same thing was asked just the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477281/initializing-an-array-of-ints).

Comment: @ybungalobill No relation there. C is **not** a strict subset of C++. You better learn this rule well.

Comment: @ybungalobill yes you did. "OP calls its "C" and then wanders why it is not in C++" means you implied that everything that is in C is also present in C++.

Comment: @H2CO3: it does not. I just said two facts. Both are true.

Comment: @H2CO3: "it's a GNU extension to C99" - Oh, interesting... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After years, I tested it just by chance, and I can confirm that it works in `g++ -std=c++11`, g++ version is 4.8.2.

Answer (score 7):

hm, you should use std::fill_n() for that task...

as stated here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html the designated inits (extention) are not implemented in GNU C++

edit: taken from here: [initialize a const array in a class initializer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c)

as a comment said, you can use std:vector to get the result desired. You could still enforce the const another way around and use fill_n.

```
int* a = new int[N];
// fill a

class C {
  const std::vector<int> v;
public:
  C():v(a, a+N) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Actually, I need to initialize const array, so, `std::fill_n()` won't work for me.

Comment: @DmitryFrank: Use `std::vector`, write a function that initializes the vector using `fill_n` and returns the result. Use this function to initialize a `const vector`.

Comment: You need `delete a;` also. Two dynamic allocation for filling array, isn't it an overkill?

Comment: After years, it works in g++ 4.8.2. :) when compiling with `-std=c++11`

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do it in C++ like that. But you can use [std::fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) algorithm to assign the values:

```
int widths[101];
fill(widths, widths+10, 1);
fill(widths+10, widths+100, 2);
fill(widths+100, widths+101, 3);
```

It is not as elegant, but it works.