# Can I initialize an array of array with all 0s?

Tags: c, arrays

I have this:

```
uint8_t buf[X][Y];
```

I would like to initialize all elements to 0. Will this do the trick:

```
uint8_t buf[X][Y] = { 0 };
```

? i.e. will it initialize all `X*Y` elements to 0?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? Did it work with `{ 1 }`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value

Comment: To initialize zeros `= {};` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you have an initializer (`{ ... }`), all elements not explicitly initialized will be initialized to zero.

Edit: Removed part that is not correct when using C.

Comment: That's valid C++, but C syntactically requires something between the braces. (C11 §6.7.9/1)

Comment: @Potatoswatter That is correct. Doesn't work with empty brackets.