# Does "char input[10]={0}" initialize all elements?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I think that this C statement:

```
 char input[10]={0}
```

assigns the first char of `input` to 0, and the remaining chars in the array to NULL. Does this happen with all C compilers?

Comment: Strictly speaking, not NULL, but `0`. Yes, it's guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some standard that guarantees it?

Comment: "The" standard guarantees it. (Pick one, there are several. But it has been part of "the" C standard for decades.) I located the relevant part in the latest http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, but the legalese obscures it too much for me.

Comment: Almost a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value. But that's for 2D arrays.

Comment: NULL pointer vs NUL character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement given explicitly initializes the first element to 0 and implicitly sets the remaining elements to 0.

Section 6.7.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) details this behavior:

> *10* If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that
>   has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>     to zero bits;
>
> ...
>
> *21* If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in
>   a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

Paragraph 21 states that if an initializer doesn't have enough elements to initialize the variable, the remaining values are initialized just like a variable with static storage duration (i.e. a variable at file scope, or a local variable declared as `static`).

As far as how something with static storage is initialized, paragraph 10 states that an arithmetic type (which `char` is) is initialized with the value 0.  This is not the same as `NULL` which is a null pointer constant, however on many implementations it has the same value.

So yes, any comforming C compiler with initialize in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you're using a partial initializer list for an array type, the remaining elements are initialized as if they were having static storage.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*, Paragraph 21

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

and, from Paragraph 10,

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

In this case, this is arithmetic type, so the elements will have values as `0`.

Answer (score -3):

it store NULL value in all position of array.

Comment: what about int x[10] = {1};  All to 1?