# Why {0} assignation works but not {5} for an array

Tags: c, arrays, array-initialization

I tried the following code:

```
int a[4] = {0};
int b[4] = {5};
int c[4];
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[3] , b[0], b[3], c[0], c[3]);
```

And got the following result:

```
0 0 5 0 random random
```

While I get why I got random values for the `c` array, I don't understand why the assignation `{5}` does not work as `{0}` and only initialize the first element of the array.

Is there a way to initialize array `b` elements to the same value different from 0? (without using a memset, or a for loop)

Comment: You don't get random values for `c`. You get what's actually in memory at `c` addresses

Comment: @JohnH it's not actually shorthand, see answers and duplicate.

Comment: Another duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int a[4] = {0};` is actually misleading. It doesn't mean "initialize all elements to `0`", it means "initialize the first element to `0` and the rest to its default value", and the rest is then initialized to `0`, resulting in all zeros.

Likewise `int b[4] = {5};` initializes the first element to `5` and the rest to `0`, so you get `5 0 0 0`.

[The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) says this:

> All array elements that are not initialized explicitly are initialized
>   implicitly the same way as objects that have static storage duration.

And for `char`, this implicit initialization sets them to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

When an array initializer has fewer elements than the array, the given initializers are applied in order and any remaining array elements are initialized to 0.  So in your case `b[0]` gets set to 5 and the rest get set to 0.

It "seems" to work for the 0 case because that value is the same as the default.