# How reading beyond end of buffer works in C?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization

Create this `x.c` test file:

```
int main(void)
{
  char x[2] = {3};
  return x[2];
}
```

Then run

```
gcc x.c; ./a.out; echo $?
```

Result is: `64`.

Why `64`?

Incidentally, why if we use

```
return x[1];
```

we get `0`? Why the `{3}` did not initialize `x[1]` too?

Comment: You pry open a deposit box belong to someone else, which you don't have access to, and find $64 dollars. Why $64? Why isn't it empty? Why not 10 or 100 or 1000 or a  chihuahua? Could it possibly be because the person who owns the deposit box is free to store whatever they please in there?

Comment: Regarding partial initialization of arrays, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520880/initializing-entire-2d-array-with-one-value/15521368#15521368

Comment: @Lundin why if we add `x[2] = 5;` the return value is `5`?

Comment: Because the police failed to catch you when you put $5 in a deposit box you have been breaking into. And you were lucky that the owner didn't show up to change the contents.

Comment: @Lundin Isn't "segmentation fault" supposed to happen in such case?

Comment: Often it will, but there are no guarantees. The police isn't guaranteed to catch 100% of all criminals. There's simply no mechanism protecting you from writing out of bounds of an array - C is low level and has less restrictions than other languages, but this freedom makes it dangerous at the same time.

Comment: @Lundin My guess is that ``Segmentation fault'' happens only when one accesses memory outside of current process, but stepping over bound of an array may happen inside of current process's memory.

Comment: That's highly system-specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ***How reading beyond end of buffer works in C?*** and ***Why 64?***

It does not "work", it's the result of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There does not exist an array element at `x[2]`.

> ***we get `0`? Why the `{3}` did not initialize `x[1]` too?***

That said, a statement like

```
 char x[2] = {3};
```

creates an array `x`, with two elements, accessed by `x[0]` and `x[1]`, and initializes `x[0]` to 3 and any remaining element to `0` (as per the rules of initialization where there are less number of initializer element that the array elements). So, that `{3}` does not initialize all the array elements to a value `3`, rather it sets the value of the first element only.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.7.9/P21

> *If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.*

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of is "Because of your perfect answer, I have now no chance of getting any reputation for making another one." Cheers.

Comment: @RubberBee It's gone now, hope my edit did not make it worse. :P

Comment: Naah, even more now.

Comment: Why if we add `x[2] = 5;` the return value is `5`?