# Memory layout in memset

Tags: c++, hex, memset

I have this *"buggy"* code :

```
int arr[15];
memset(arr, 1, sizeof(arr));
```

`memset` sets each byte to 1, but since `int` is generally 4-bytes, it won't give the desired output. I know that each `int` in the array will we initalized to `0x01010101 = 16843009`. Since I have a weak (very) understanding of hex values and memory layouts, can someone explain why it gets initialized to that hex value ? What will be the case if I have say, 4, in place of 1 ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, because you already have the answer in your first line. *memset sets each byte to 1 = 0x01, since int is generally 4-bytes* 4 bytes will be set to 0x01010101 . Can you clarify your weakness of understand in the memory layout? This might be more helpful.

Comment: Remember that `sizeof(arr)` == 60 (bytes) not 15 (integers).

Comment: Yeah, so I know I'm assigning every 1 byte with a 4-byte value `1`, how can a 4-byte value be assigned to a single byte ? @acraig5075

Comment: Are you sure your real question is not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477281/initializing-an-array-of-ints

Comment: Nope. NOPE. That's why I wrote "buggy". @UmNyobe

Comment: @Jarvis: do you want to set '1' for each bit in array?

Comment: Nope, NOPE (again, and why would I do something like that). I was just asking how it happens since it's already happening. @pstanisz

Comment: My objective was to know how 4-byte value is assigned to 1-byte, and what will be the hexadecimal representations involved, which are resolved now, so please lift the down-vote from question if you have down-voted. @UmNyobe

Comment: May I point out `std::fill`? Works on arrays as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) does is

> Converts the value ch to unsigned char and copies it into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by dest.

So, first your value (`1`) will be converted to unsigned char, which occupies 1 byte, so that will be `0b00000001`. Then memset will fill the whole array's memory with these values. Since an `int` takes 4 bytes on your machine, the value of each `int` int the array would be `00000001000000010000000100000001` which is 16843009. If you place another value instead of `1`, the array's memory will be filled with that value instead.

Answer (score 2):

If I trust the man page

> The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to an unsigned char) to the string b.

In your case it will convert 0x00000001 (as an int) into 0x01 (as an unsigned char), then fill each byte of the memory with this value. You can fit 4 of that in an int, that is, each int will become 0x01010101.

If you had 4, it would be casted into the unsigned char 0x04, and each int would be filled with 0x04040404.

Does that make sense to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) converts its second argument to an `unsigned char` which is one byte. One byte is eight bits, and you're setting each byte to the value `1`. So we get

```
0b00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001
```

or in hexadecimal,

```
0x01010101
```

or the decimal number `16843009`. Why that value? Because

```
0b00000001000000010000000100000001 = 1*2^0 + 1*2^8 + 1*2^16 + 1*2^24
                                   = 1 + 256 + 65536 + 16777216
                                   = 16843009
```

Each group of four binary digits corresponds to one hexadecimal digit. Since `0b0000` = `0x0` and `0b0001` = `0x1`, your final value is `0x01010101`. With `memset(arr, 4, sizeof(arr));` you would get `0x04040404` and with `12` you would get `0x0c0c0c0c`.