# Why printing a static 2D array in C gives me seg fault?

Tags: c, arrays

I just want to print out a static array (2D array) in C using functions. I use gcc as my compiler. When I try to run my code it gives me a seg fault and I dont have any idea why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_out_an_array(int n, int m, int tab[n][m])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            printf("tab[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tab[i][j]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int tab[2][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
    print_out_an_array(tab, 2, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could update this to reflect your actual code? (which this clearly isn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of answering the original solution whose solution is obvious, I answer the other one from your comment.

Your array is a

```
int[][N]
```

while you pass a

```
int ** to your function.
```

These are completely different from each other:

- An `int[][N]` has all values from all dimensions beneath each other.
- An `int **`, however, points to one or more pointers, in turn pointing to the real values.

At `int[][]`, you can omit one level of indirection and can turn it into a

```
int (*)[N]
```

i. e. a pointer to an array. This array must be of determined size, which isn't fulfilled in your case as well.

Comment: I think what you wrote here is the most important part. Where can I read about it more?

Comment: @BrianBrown In a good C book or tutorial (but, alas, I can't name one). And surely in many Q/As here on SO (but I cannot tell a concrete one, but there must be many).

Answer (score 3):

your function call and function definition doesnt match

your function call
`print_out_an_array(tab, 2, 4);` 
but in function definition your first argument is `int`
`void print_out_an_array(int n, int m, int tab[n][m])`

make the arguments same, like:

change function call to 
``print_out_an_array(2, 4, tab);`

**update**:
check [this code](http://ideone.com/etvMlo) it works

and also read this for reference [C, passing 2 dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750247/c-passing-2-dimensional-array)

Comment: @BrianBrown Because it is not an `int**` what you have.

Comment: @BrianBrown; You are passing incomplete pointer type to your function `fun`.

Answer (score 3):

In your function definition, first parameter is `int` type but you are calling your function with first argument as `int **`. Change your function call to

```
print_out_an_array(2, 4, tab);
```

---

About the question in your comment:

> Ok, but how about this code: http://ideone.com/Z4mHkb why it gives me an error?

**Function parameters `**tab` and `tab[n][m]` are not equivalent**. Compiler, on seeing `tab [m][n]` as function parameter, interprets it as

```
void fun(int (*)[m]tab, int n, int m)
```

i.e , it interprets `tab` as a pointer to an array of `m` integers. While on seeing  `int **tab`, it simply interprets `tab` as a pointer to a *pointer to integer* (or an array of pointers ( `int *tab[]`) to `int` ).