# Allocate memory 2d array in function C

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d, allocation

How to allocate dynamic memory for 2d array in function ?
I tried this way:

```
int main()
{
  int m=4,n=3;
  int** arr;
  allocate_mem(&arr,n,m);
}


void allocate_mem(int*** arr,int n, int m)
{
  *arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    *arr[i]=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your code is wrong at `*arr[i]=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));` because the [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of the `[]` operator is higher than the `*` deference operator: In the expression `*arr[i]`, first `arr[i]` is evaluated then `*` is applied. What you need is the reverse (dereference `arr`, then apply `[]`).

Use parentheses like this: `(*arr)[i]` to override operator precedence. Now, your code should look like this:

```
void allocate_mem(int*** arr, int n, int m)
{
  *arr = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    (*arr)[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
}
```

To understand further what happens in the above code, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240540/dynamically-allocating-array-explain/19240932#19240932).

It is important that you always deallocate dynamically allocated memory explicitly once you are done working with it. To free the memory allocated by the above function, you should do this:

```
void deallocate_mem(int*** arr, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free((*arr)[i]);
    free(*arr); 
}
```

Additionally, a better way to create a 2D array is to [allocate contiguous memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477234/difference-b-w-allocating-memory-to-2d-array-in-1-go-or-row-by-row) with a single `malloc()` function call as below:

```
int* allocate_mem(int*** arr, int n, int m)
{
  *arr = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
  int *arr_data = malloc( n * m * sizeof(int));
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
     (*arr)[i] = arr_data + i * m ;
  return arr_data; //free point
}
```

To deallocate this memory:

```
void deallocate_mem(int*** arr, int* arr_data){
    free(arr_data);
    free(*arr);
}
```

Notice that in the second technique malloc is called only two times, and so in the deallocation code free is called only two times instead of calling it in a loop. So this technique should be better.

Comment: @user2089491 If it solved your problem, then accept this answer as correct by clicking the "check mark" on the left.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this: Just single allocation

```
int** allocate2D(int m, int n)
{
    int **a = (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(int *) + (m * n * sizeof(int)));

    int *mem = (int *)(a + m);

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        a[i] = mem + (i * n);
    }

    return a;
}
```

To Free:

```
free(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your array does not need to be resized (well, you can, but il will be a bit more complicated), there is an easier/more efficient way to build 2D arrays in C.

Take a look at http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html.

The second method (for the array called array2) is quite simple, less painful (try to add the tests for mallocs' return value), and way more efficient.

I've just benchmarked it, for a 200x100 array, allocated and deallocated 100000 times:

- Method 1 : 1.8s
- Method 2 : 47ms

And the data in the array will be more contiguous, which may speed things up (you may get some more efficient techniques to copy, reset... an array allocated this way).

Comment: I partially agree with you. If you are working with **huge** arrays (several hundreds, event thousands of Mo), or maybe in some constrained systems, this method might not be suitable since you may run into large-block-from-heap-allocation troubles (but there some chance that you migh be screwed whatever method you choose). But for most cases, this method is quite safe, and really efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Rather allocating the memory in many different block, one can allocate this in a consecutive block of memory.
Do the following:

```
int** my2DAllocation(int rows,int columns)
{
   int i;
   int header= rows *sizeof(int *);
   int data=rows*cols*sizeof(int);
   int ** rowptr=(int **)malloc(header+data);
   if(rowptr==NULL)
   {
      return NULL:
   }
   int * buf=(int*)(rowptr+rows);
   for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
      rowptr[i]=buf+i*cols;
   } 
   return rowptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an unnecessarily complicated way of allocating space for an array. Consider this idiom:

```
int main(void) {
    size_t m = 4, n = 3;
    int (*array)[m];
    array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: `2d_array` is not a valid identifier though!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code for allocating memory to 2 dimensional array.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    void main(void)
    {
    int **p;//double pointer holding a 2d array
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    p=(int**)(malloc(sizeof(int*)));//memory allocation for double pointer
    for(j=(3*i+1);j<(3*i+4);j++)
    {
    *p = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)));//memory allocation for pointer holding integer array
    **p = j;                  
    printf(" %d",**p);//print integers in a row 
    printf("\n");
    p++;
    }
    }
    }
```

Output of the above code is:-

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

In order to understand 2 dimensional array in terms of pointers, we need to understand how it will be allocated in memory, it should be something like this:-

```
                1    2    3
    1000 -->   100  104  108

                4    5    6
    1004 -->   200  204  208

                7    8    9
    1008 -->   300  304  308
```

from the above, we understand that, when we allocate memory to pointer p which is a double pointer, it is pointing to an array of integers, so in this example, we see that the 0x1000 is pointer p.

This pointer is pointing to integer pointer *p which is array of integers, when memory is allocated inside the inner for loop, during first iteration the pointer is 0x100 which is pointing to integer value 1, when we assign **p = j. Similarly it will be pointing to 2 and 3 in the next iterations in the loop.

Before the next iteration of the outer loop, double pointer is incremented, inside the next iteration, as is seen in this example the pointer is now at 0x1004 and is pointing to integer pointer which is an array of integers 4,5,6 and similarly for the next iterations in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
 void allocate_mem(int*** arr,int n, int m)
{
  *arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    *(arr+i)=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

2d Array dynamically array using malloc:

```
int row = 4;
int column = 4;
int val = 2;
// memory allocation using malloc   

int **arrM = (int**)malloc (row*sizeof(int*));

for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    arrM[i] = (int*)malloc(column*sizeof(int));
    // insert the value for each field
    for (int j =0;j<column;j++,val++)
    {
      arrM[i][j]     = val;
    }
}

// De-allocation

for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    free(arrM[i]);
}
free(arrM);
arrM = 0;

//
// Now using New operator:
//

int **arr = new int*[row];
int k = 1;
for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[column];
    // insert the value for each field
    for (int j =0;j<column;j++,k++)
    {
      arr[i][j]  = k;
    }
}
cout<<"array value is = "<<*(*(arr+0)+0)<<endl;
cout<<"array value is = "<<*(*(arr+3)+2)<<endl;

// Need to deallcate memory;

for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
delete [] arr[i];
}
delete []arr;
arr = 0;
```