# How to allocate memory C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array

I need `int matrix[x][x]` field to be allocated, `x` is user input and I want the rows to be one continous block of memory.

Lets say user inputs `x=5` and when I do this

```
matrix [1][6] = 1
```

I want it to do this

```
matrix [2][0] = 1
```

Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: i have a text file in which is matrix like  00101\n01011\n01011\n01011\n01010\n     and i need it to be loaded into   matrix [5][5]  user first writes the matrix into text file then run program and input number of rows

Comment: Do you want to allocate with "0"'s or just dynamically allocate an array? You kind of lost me with the matrix[2][0]=1 part..

Comment: Do you need help in allocating `matrix`? Do you really need the kind of indexing you're describing?

Comment: Is it just that you want it to wrap (since the 6 would otherwise be beyond the end of that array)?

Comment: If you use C++ you can create specific classes and operators for this. Otherwise, you can create a simple C function to transform "wrong" indexes into correct ones.

Comment: well no i dont i have solved it that the matrix in text file is just one continous line but whne i want it to be formated im not able to load it properly into matrix in program for calculations

Comment: yes exactli i otherwise it will be out of range but i want it to be in continous block of memory so it will wrap to next line

Comment: "when I do `matrix [1][6] = 1` I want it to do `matrix [2][0] = 1`??? Do you even understand yourself what it is that you want to do?

Comment: shouldn't it be that `matrix [1][6]` is equal to `matrix[2][1]`? If you think of a linearized access, now both point to the 11th element

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a slightly different approach:

Allocate a 1-dimensional data-structure that holds the data in a "line". Then write a get-function that linearizes these coordinates.

```
class linearMatrix{
    int dim;
    int* memory;

public:
    linearMatrix(int d) : dim(d) {
        memory = (int*) malloc(dim*dim*sizeof(int));
        // insert code to fill the matrix
    }

    int get(int x, int y){
        int index = x*dim + y;
        return memory[index];
    }

    void set(int x, int y, int value){
        int index = x*dim + y;
        memory[index] = value;
    }

    ~linearMatrix(){
        free(memory);
    }
};
```

The memory will be always continous this way and it allows to insert some checks if coordinates are really OK. Of course, you have to remove all the \n characters from your matrix string so that only the raw numbers are in the array.

The linearMatrix would be used somehow like this:

```
linearMatrix matrix(5);
// make sure the matrix gets filled somehow
// these 2 calls access the same memory location
matrix.set(1,6) = 1;
matrix.set(2,1) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following way to allocate the array, so as to have all elements contiguous in memory :

```
int n;
char** array2d=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
if(array2d==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
array2d[0]=malloc(n*n*sizeof(char));
if(array2d[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
int i;
for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    array2d[i] =& array2d[0][i*n];
}
```

The elements can be acceded by `array2d[i][j]`.

A 2D array is an array of pointers to starts of rows, all items being allocated by a single call to `malloc()`.

This way to allocate memory is useful if the data is to by treated by libraries such as fftw or lapack. The pointer to the data is `array[0]`.

Indeed, writing `array2d[0][n]=42` or `array2d[1][0]=42` performs the same thing !

See :

- [Allocate memory 2d array in function C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c)
- [difference b/w allocating memory to 2D array in 1 go or row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477234/difference-b-w-allocating-memory-to-2d-array-in-1-go-or-row-by-row)

In a function :

```
int alloc2d(int n,char ***array2d){
    *array2d=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    if(*array2d==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    (*array2d)[0]=malloc(n*n*sizeof(char));
    if((*array2d)[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    int i;
    for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        (*array2d)[i] =& (*array2d)[0][i*n];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

called from main by `char** array2d;alloc2d(42,&array2d);`

Test code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int alloc2d(int n,char ***array2d){
    *array2d=malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
    if(*array2d==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    (*array2d)[0]=malloc(n*n*sizeof(char));
    if((*array2d)[0]==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    int i;
    for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        (*array2d)[i] =& (*array2d)[0][i*n];
    }
}

int free2d(char **array2d){
    free(array2d[0]);
    free(array2d);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n=42;
    char** array2d;
    alloc2d(n,&array2d);

    array2d[0][n]=13;
    printf("%d\n",array2d[1][0]);
    free2d(array2d);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled by `gcc main.c -o main`. As expected, output is 13. A function to free the memory was added.