# Allocate memory 2d array in function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for a 2D array inside a function in C++.
A question exactly like this has been asked except that it is written using malloc and dealloc, so I was wondering if you could help me convert it to use new and delete. Here is the other question:

[Allocate memory 2d array in function C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c)

I tried changing it to the following code, but I'm getting errors.

```
void assign_memory_for_board(int ROWS, int COLS, int *** board) {
   *board = new int**[ROWS];
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
       (*board)[i] = new int*[COLS];
   }
}
```

Here is the answer that worked using malloc and dealloc:

```
void allocate_mem(int*** arr, int n, int m)
{
   *arr = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      (*arr)[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why so many stars? Just use appropriate standard containers.

Comment: Unless otherwise constrained, always prefer `std::vector` or `std::array`, and consider using a 2D view to a 1D physical array.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by standard containers?

Comment: A standard container like std::vector.

Comment: `std::vector` et. al.

Comment: What is `dealloc` and where is it used?

Comment: Hello everyone, why was this question downvoted 3 times? I'd like to know so I can ask better questions later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra stars. The function should be

```
void assign_memory_for_board(int ROWS, int COLS, int *** board) {
   *board = new int*[ROWS];
   for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
       (*board)[i] = new int[COLS];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So does C++ take care of some of the pointers? Because in C there were more pointers.

Comment: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `char* hoge = new char[10];` <- `<type of pointer to elements of the array> <variable name> = new <type of elements of the array>[<number of eiements>];`

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
int AllocMatrix(int ***K, int h, int c){
    *K = new int *[h];
    for(int i=0; i < h; i++){
        *K[i] = new int[c];
    }
    if(K == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Avaiable!"<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```