# C++ Allocate a dynamic 2d array in function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

gals and everything in between, first off, I want to say sorry for noob/duplicate question.

TL;DR I want to allocate memory for a 2d array of chars, however I can only do so when the program calls alloc(). Any help is appreciated.

Since you guys love code, here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define LOG(x) cout<<endl<<x<<endl

void alloc(char ***add){

    cout<<"Size: ";int s;cin>>s;
        *add = new char *[s];
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            *(add)[i] = new char[s];
            cout<<add[i][i]<<" ; ";
        }
}

int main() {
    char **c;

    alloc(&c);
    for (int i =0;i<2;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout<<c[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
cin.get();
}
```

Now whenever I run this code, I get the following error: **Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**.

Also, in the debugger, when the function gets called and I input the size of the array, I get a **use of undeclared identifier 'c'** error.

Thank you and I apologize again for noob or duplicate question, but I did try the answer I got from [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857640/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c), alas, to no avail.

Comment: ***I get a use of undeclared identifier 'c' error*** That would prevent you from getting an executable so you could not debug anything.

Comment: Ty for your input @drescherjm , but as I said, im a noob. Why it works and I am able to click the debug icon is beyond me at this point.

Comment: What ever source you use for learning c++ you really should choose something else. The shown code is far from what you would do in c++. The way `alloc` is implemented prevents you from properly releasing the allocated memory and doing boundary tests.

Comment: @t.niese and I don't suppose you could recommend something else? I learned what I know mostly from the internet and stackoverflow.

Comment: There is [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is a Q&A platform for specific questions but not a good starting point to learn a language. You should first learn the basics and concepts of a language, and that is done by using a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*(add)[i]` does not look quite right, it indexes the add variable and dereferences the pointer afterwards. Those parentheses have no effect.

Try the opposite order, i.e. `(*add)[i]`

Comment: Just tried that and I get **Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**

Comment: add[i][i] is also wrong I think. You need to learn to use a debugger to see on which line it crashes...

Comment: I use add[i][i] as a shorthand for *(*(add+i)+i)

Comment: Ok, made s=2 and just set a breakpoint at (*add)[i] = new char[s];

Now I get: *(c+1)=error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'.

I get the sigsegv and the crash after the second time (*add)[i] = new char[s] is executed.

Comment: Good, I think you will figure it out. Just step the program until it crashes.

Comment: Thats what Im doing, the program crashes after it allocates a new char[] for (*add)[i].

Comment: Thing is, I dont know why it crashes. The same code worked in the link I provided...

Comment: It seems I am getting an invalid address when I try to cout add[i][i], but i can only take 2 values, 0 and 1, since I am trying to create a 2d array. How the frickfrack am I going out of bounds???

Comment: Don't forget that "add" is of type char***, while "c"  is of type char**. "add" is a pointer to your 2d array, not the 2d array itself. You need to keep that in mind when indexing it.

Comment: **cout<<add[i][i]** should be **cout<<(*add)[i][i]** 

Thanks @Sven. Nvm my last. All is good now. Thanks :))