# Allocating memory to **

Tags: c

I have this struct

```
typedef struct{
 char **palavras;
}no;
```

and I want to allocate memory to this array of strings basically

and I can't do this, since it says it expects something before the '('

```
no *atual;

atual->(*palavras)=calloc(1,sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allocate memory 2d array in function C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c)

Comment: @KenY-N: Althought the linked question uses the term "2D array", this is not a 2D array. As we don' know what OP intends, it is hasrd to say if he wants a 2D array or the pointer to pointer construct wich is **not** a 2D array, nor can it point to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in several stages:

- First, allocate memory to `atual`,
- Next, allocate memory to `palavras`
- Finally, allocate memory to elements of `palavras`

Assuming that you need to allocate 10 `palavras`, you can do it like this:

```
no *atual = malloc(sizeof(no));
atual->palavras = malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
atual->palavras[0] = malloc(20);
...
```

Comment: oh thank you I get it, I was doing the oppossite, I tought you allocate memory for palavras with **, my bad yeah :/

Answer (score -1):

You should access `palavras` by `atual->palavras`, e.g. `atual->palavras = calloc(5, sizeof(char *))`, and dereference the `char **` by `*atual->palavras`. You may also allocate memory for the `char *` pointers by `atual->palavras` by, say, `atual->palavras[0] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char))`.