# How can i dynamically allocate 2 dimensional array for an specific purpose?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I want to write a program to keep usernames and passwords on a dynamic 2 dimensional array. but I don't know how can I do this?

can you help me? and also my boss force me not to use structures.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information, like language you use, what had you already tried, ....

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To keep usernames and passwords it is a bad idea to use a 2d array unless the number of users is small.

You need to keep them either in a trie or a hash table.

If you do not need to remove users then you can also use bloom filters for some operations (combined with some of previous methods).