# Returning pointer to allocated memory?

Tags: c

My task is to write a function `int *matrica1(int n)`. This function must create a matrix dimensions nxn and then you have to allocate its memory and in the main you have to write the elements of the matrix. I have a problem when returning pointer `mat1` to `**p` and when i call `**p` i get a address instead of a number but when i call `**mat1` in the function i get the number. I do not understand ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *matrica1(int n);

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Input dimension of matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int **p = matrica1(n);


    printf("Matrix \n\n");

    int i;
    n = n*n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf(" %d ", **(p+i));//I keep getting an address
    }
    return 0;
}

int *matrica1(int n){
    int mat[n][n];
    int i, j;
    int k=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            mat[i][j] = j+k;
        }
        k++;
    }

    int size = n*n;
    int **mat1 = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    int m = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            mat1[m] = &mat[i][j];
            m++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n**mat1 = %d", **mat1);//Here it returns me a number

    return mat1;
}
```

[here how it looks like when running it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DCwY.png)

Comment: active warning !

Comment: mat is on stack and pointers to this array are invalid as soon as you leave the function.

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062718/allocate-memory-2d-array-in-function-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the address of a local variable.

`mat1` contains pointers to element of `mat`.  When `matrica1` returns, `mat` goes out of scope, so pointers to its elements no longer point to valid memory.  Dereferencing these pointers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Other problems:

- The memory you're assigning to `mat1` is not the right size.  Because it is an array of `int *`, you should be allocating `size*sizeof(int *)` bytes, not `size*sizeof(int)` bytes.
- `matrica1` is defined to return a `int *` but you're returning an `int **` and assigning the result to an `int **`.  The return type of the function must match what you're returning.

Rather than having `mat1` be an array of `int *`, make it an array of `int` and copy the *values* of `mat` rather than the *addresses*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *matrica1(int n);

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Unesite dimenziju matrice:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Have p match return type of function
    int *p = matrica1(n);


    printf("Matrix \n\n");

    int i;
    n = n*n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        // print array elements
        printf(" %d ", *(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}

int *matrica1(int n){
    int mat[n][n];
    int i, j;
    int k=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            mat[i][j] = j+k;
        }
        k++;
    }

    int size = n*n;
    // change type of mat1 from int ** to int *, keep size the same
    int *mat1 = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    int m = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            // assign values of mat instead of addresses
            mat1[m] = mat[i][j];
            m++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n*mat1 = %d", *mat1);

    return mat1;
}
```

Output:

```
Unesite dimenziju matrice:5


*mat1 = 0Matrix 

 0  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  2  3  4  5  6  3  4  5  6  7  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: When matrica1 returns, mat goes out of scope. Can you please explain that. Dose that mean you are never allowed to return an array of addresses in c ?

Comment: @Marko You can return an array of address (or a single address) **provided** that address is not the address of a local variable.  Because `mat` no longer exists when the function `matrica1` returns, a pointer to it is not valid.  The memory that was used by `mat` can be repurposed for something else.

Comment: Thank you, you have really helped me.