# Is it correct this declaration of a matrix as a double pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I am new in C programming language and I don't know whether my code is correct and efficient enough or there is something I am misunderstanding. The only thing I want to do is to allocate dynamic memory in my main function for a matrix of n rows and m columns. Then, I want to initialize it by passing it by reference to function matrix_access. Finally, I just print the values to verify the matrix has been initialized correctly.

I have done it by means of declaring **matrix, but I have seen in some other websites declarations as a triple pointer and I don't get it. In my code, I am interpreting my memory allocation as allocating first memory to the first element in each row and then, allocating memory for each element in the row. Is it correct or my understanding is completely wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void matrix_access(double ** matrix, int n, int m);

int main()
{
    int n = 5, m = 4;
    double **matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(double*));  // pointer to the first element of each row
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(double)); // pointer to each element in the row
    }
    
    matrix_access(matrix,n,m);
    
    printf("The values are\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            {
                    printf("%lf ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    return 0;
}


void matrix_access(double ** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    int arr1[5][5] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3},
                       { 2, 3, 4, 5},
                       { 4, 27, 6, 7},
                       { 5, 4, 3, 2},
                       { 2, 5, 4, 3} };
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
        {
            matrix[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You only need a tripple pointer if the function is supposed to change your `**matrix`. You only pass your pointer by value to your function and the pointer is not modified. Only the elements where it points to are touched.

Comment: Looks fine. This is the typical pattern for a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) - one of [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12462615/2505965) to construct a two-dimensional array. If you have seen a different way using three levels of indirection, then it may be that similar to the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062765/2505965), where the allocation is occurring in a different function. Beware of the [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), however.

Comment: @user23326904,, Rather than only describe code with "I have seen in some other websites declarations as a triple pointer", post that code or a link to it.

Comment: @ser23326904,  " Is it correct or my understanding is completely wrong?"  --> Looks OK (expect for allocation failures), but not enough code to see if it it correct for general use.  You are not completely wrong.  It is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have done it by means of declaring **matrix,

I do not like this approach to representing matrices, but it is nonetheless relatively common.

> but I have seen in some other websites declarations as a triple pointer and I don't get it.

One might use a triple pointer as a function argument if one wants the function to modify a double pointer (itself) whose address the caller passes.  The code you've presented does not rely on that mechanism for exchanging data.

> In my code, I am interpreting my memory allocation as allocating first memory to the first element in each row and then, allocating memory for each element in the row.

Your code looks ok, but that description is off. The structure you are creating is an array of pointers, each one pointing to the data for a different row.  Thus, your first allocation is for the array of pointers.  None of these are, themselves, elements of the matrix you are modeling.  The later allocations are each for *all* the elements of a single row.

> Is it correct or my understanding is completely wrong?

Your code looks fine to me.  Your understanding is a little off.

---

For what it's worth, when I can rely on fixed array dimensions or on variably-modified types, I prefer to use a contiguously allocated representation for matrices.  Something like this:

```
void matrix_access(int n, int m, double (*matrix)[m]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 5, m = 4;
    double (*matrix)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof(*matrix));  // all elements
    
    matrix_access(n, m, matrix);
    
    printf("The values are\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(matrix); // only one free needed for the whole matrix

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: John, can you do that? `void matrix_access(int n, int m, double (*matrix)[m]) {...` specifying the size of the inner array from a previous parameter?  Is that standard?
Anyway, you had better written `double matrix[][m]` (a bit more readable the intention)

Comment: Yes you can, @LuisColorado, provided that your implementation supports VLAs.  But it does need to be a *previous* parameter, not a subsequent one.  That's why I reordered the arguments relative to the OP's version.  Also, you are right that `double matrix[][m]` is a viable alternative spelling, but I account it a matter of style whether and when to prefer that form.

Comment: Yeah... I know that... but my question was more if it is included in the standard, and from what version.  The thing is that I work with matrices and this can simplify some interfaces... and avoid to allocate the matrices on the heap (I'm working on embedded sw)  Do you know if it is included in std11?

Comment: @LuisColorado, by "Yes you can" I meant, "yes, *it is standard*".  It follows from the allowance for VLAs in the general rules for declaring arrays in C99 and later, and from the fact that an identifier's scope starts immediately after the end of its declarator.  There is even a special provision for using `*` to designate VLA dimensions in function prototypes that are not part of definitions (C99 6.7.5.3/12), which supports the ability to omit parameter names from such prototypes -- such as would otherwise be used to specify the VLA dimension.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1

> I don't know whether my code is correct?

Yes (only improvements like add `free`(also for each row) and code formatting)

#### Question 2

> efficient enough?, The only thing I want to do is to allocate dynamic memory in my main function for a matrix of n rows and m columns. Then, I want to initialize it by passing it by reference to function matrix_access. Finally, I just print the values to verify the matrix has been initialized correctly.

As your `matrix_access` is not doing complex operation better is single allocation `malloc(n * m * sizeof(double));`
`passing it by reference`
Also in C there is not references, it's just pointers

#### Question 3

> I am interpreting my memory allocation as allocating first memory to the first element in each row and then, allocating memory for each element in the row. Is it correct or my understanding is completely wrong?

Your first allocation by `malloc(n * sizeof(double*));` is creating array of pointers and each pointer in it will represent a single row, that you are allocating by `malloc(m * sizeof(double))`. Also I encourage you to not think about it as `pointer to first element` but `pointer to array`(row in this case), in the end it's the same but in theory you can access any element, so it's not a pointer to one element but whole array

### Reasons for different approaches

#### One allocation vs many

When you are doing one allocation you are guaranteed to that will be single contiguous block of memory, so elements are closer in memory and it's may speed up your application by reducing number of cache misses by CPU. Also it requires less memory as each call to `malloc` creates block with metadata information about it for HEAP allocator, so if there is less calls to malloc it consume less memory.

One of the downside is you can't easier swap rows or columns, for example when I was implementing `Reducing Matrix to Row Echelon Form`, it requires sometimes  to swap rows, and when you have a single block of memory you have to copy everything that may me less effective.

On the other hand when you have Matrix where each row is different allocation to swap rows, it's just swap pointer much faster than swapping each individual element of the array.

In most cases when your data is not big single allocation is better and simpler, as you don't need to `free` every single block manually

#### Row or columns?

When you are creating any two dimensional data structure you can decide what should be easier accessible next and previous column or row, in your case as each easier to access other columns within the row, but in some cases may need to be optimal for next column. It can be seen in Databases most of them are row oriented, but in some cases when you need to do many operation on all elements on column, column oriented Database might be easier

#### Is it correct this declaration of a matrix as a double pointer in C?

The answer is it depends on the needs, looking at just code yes but you are not `free`ing memory

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:** the declaration and the initialization is correct.  It allows you to reference the two dimensional array *based on dynamic dimensions.*

---

**Slow answer:** Your write:

```
void matrix_access(double ** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    int arr1[5][5] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3},
                       { 2, 3, 4, 5},
                       { 4, 27, 6, 7},
                       { 5, 4, 3, 2},
                       { 2, 5, 4, 3} };
```

This declares `double (arr1[5])[5];`.  This is, `arr1[5]` is an array of 5 arrays of 5 elements of type `double`.

But `double **matrix` is a double pointer (not a `double` pointer)... a pointer that *can reference* an array of any number of pointers to arrays of `double`.

Arrays are declared in C statically, this is, at compilation time.  The reason for this is that C *must know each type X completely before creating a variable of type X,* and **the array size fixes the type itself** (this means `double[5]` is a different type than `double[6]`, and of course a different type than `double *`)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = arr1[i][j];
            }
        }
}
```

This results in that, despite being the same expression, it represents different things, as `matrix` is a pointer to an array of pointers, and `matrix[i]` is a pointer to an array of `double`s, while `arr1[i]` is an array of 5 `double`s, that can be indexed to get each of the individual cells.

Finally, if you don't want to deal with a huge amount of `malloc`s, you can save time and memory, if you build your `matrix` the following way:

```
    double **matrix = calloc(rows, sizeof *matrix);
    double *cells   = calloc(rows * cols, sizeof *cells), 
           *p       = cells;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++, p += cols) {
        matrix[i] = p;
    }
```

This way, when you want to free your matrix you have only to do

```
    free(matrix[0]);
    free(matrix);
    /* ... and optionally */
    matrix = NULL;  /* to avoid dangling pointers to freed memory */
```

You make a malloc for the array of pointers and another for the array of cells, two in total.