# How to use multiple pointers to a struct that contains a pointer to another struct with mutiple pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to use an array of pointers to a struct that has a pointer in it to another struct that is being used with an array of pointers.

I can write the code for a two single structs and it works. However, I am not sure how to deal with the introduction of the array of pointers.
Sample code:

```
typedef struct {
    double vx;
} particle_t;
    
typedef struct {
    int m;
    int n;
    particle_t *inparticles;    // Pointer to particles inside grid
} grid_t;
    
particle_t *particles = (particle_t*) malloc( 3 * sizeof(particle_t) );
grid_t *grid = (grid_t*) malloc( 3 * sizeof(grid_t) ); // trying 3 pointers

if( particles==NULL || grid==NULL ){
    puts("Unable to allocate memory");
    exit(1);}

// fill the structure 
grid[1].inparticles = particles[1]; // I am not sure how to link these
grid[2].inparticles = particles[2]; // these lines give incompatible types error
grid[3].inparticles = particles[3];
grid[1].m = 5;
grid[1].n = 3;
grid[1].inparticles -> vx = 15;
```

Thank you in advance!

Update:

I realized that what I should be doing is use the inparticles pointer to point to multiple particles in the same grid pointer? How I can change the code so I can be able to do that?
for example:

```
grid[0].inparticles[0] = particles[0];
grid[0].inparticles[1] = particles[1];
grid[0].inparticles[2] = particles[2];
```

declare it as an array somehow? would I need memory allocation for it as well?

Comment: Note that C arrays are indexed from 0, not from 1.  Your `grid[3]` and `particles[3]` each overrun the bounds of the corresponding allocated object.

Comment: Check out the following post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023013/how-to-use-an-array-of-pointers-inside-a-structure-correctly*emphasized text*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an array of pointers inside a structure correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023013/how-to-use-an-array-of-pointers-inside-a-structure-correctly)

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger for the reminder!

Comment: @SanketAgarwal it does not because it only uses an array of pointers on one structure, not on both.

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: Can you explain please? @mlp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Don%27t+cast+the+return+value+from+malloc%28%29

Comment: What are n and m? Are they relevant for this question?

Comment: @tstanisl No, they are not relevant. I added them just to demonstrate that the struct has other members.

Comment: @YaserBaqi If possible, could you elaborate what you are trying to construct ? For example what is a grid and what is a particle here ?

Comment: @YaserBaqi So none of the answers listed bellow had answered your question yet?...

Answer (score 1):

Each member of `particles` has type `particle_t`.  The `inparticles` member of `grid_t` has type `particle_t *`.  So you want:

```
grid[1].inparticles = &particles[1];
grid[2].inparticles = &particles[2];
grid[3].inparticles = &particles[3];
```

Addressing your update, if you want to have `inparticles` point to various members of `particles`, you would need to change the `inparticles` to be a pointer-to-pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    int m;
    int n;
    particle_t **inparticles;
} grid_t;
```

Then you would have to allocate space for an array of pointers, then assign each pointer:

```
grid[0].inparticles = malloc(3 * sizeof(particle_t *));
grid[0].inparticles[0] = &particles[0];
grid[0].inparticles[1] = &particles[1];
grid[0].inparticles[2] = &particles[2];
```

Comment: I am not sure if I should ask this here. However, how would I use the inparticles pointer to point to multiple particles in the same grid pointer? declare it as an array somehow? would I need memory allocation for it as well? @dbush

Comment: @YaserBaqi See my edit.  Just point `inparticles` to `particles`.

Comment: Clarification, I'm only trying to point to a subset of all the particles. @dbush

Comment: @YaserBaqi Would it always point to 3, or could the number of particles it points to vary?

Comment: It could vary. @dbush

Comment: @YaserBaqi I made further updates to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

### Design

> I am trying to use an array of pointers to a struct that has a pointer in it to another struct that is being used with an array of pointers.

In other words, we must find a way to design "An **array of pointers** to a **struct**, which contains **a pointer** to another **struct** *used as an array*".

I will focus on this.

### Array of pointers

> However, I am not sure how to deal with the introduction of the array of pointers.

Well, we don't have *any* array of pointers in your code... you must create one first.

C pointers, arrays, structures and all their combinations have *countless* threads *all over* the internet which have been answered *several* times. I will show you a few basic examples so you can be up and running, just don't expect me to give you a whole lesson of pointers.

---

## Solutions

### Design

Here is the code (I changed some variable names to make it more readable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    double value;
}Particle;

typedef struct
{
    int width;
    int height;
    Particle *particles;
}Grid;

Grid *createGrid(int width, int height)
{
    Grid *result = malloc(sizeof(Grid));
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while allocating memory for the grid structure!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else
    {
        result->width = width;
        result->height = height;
        result->particles = malloc(sizeof(Particle) * width*height);
    }
    return result;
}

void destroyGrid(Grid *grid)
{
    free(grid->particles);
    free(grid);
}

int main()
{
    Grid *grids[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        grids[i] = createGrid(5, 3);
    
    /* Assign, modify, read or copy values from the array of pointers here */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        destroyGrid(grids[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I introduced 2 functions to make your life easier: **createGrid** and **destroyGrid**.

The first one will need you to specify 2 arguments: the `width` and `height` (`m` and `n` in your code) of a grid. The function is then going to allocate memory and return a **pointer** to the grid it just created.

The second one will need you to specify 1 argument: a **pointer** to a grid. The function is then going to free all the memory the first function allocated, avoiding any memory leaks.

I've also added an **array of pointers** in the main function: `grids`. This, in combination with the usage of the functions described above (all in the main function), solves the first issue.

The final design can be read as follows:
"We have an **array of pointers** to a **struct** (`grids`), which contains a **pointer** to another **struct** (`particles`) *which should be used as an array*".

### Array of pointers

You may be wondering now: "OK, so how am I supposed to use this array-of-pointers-to-a-structure-confusing-stuff?" As I said before, I will show you a practical example only.

Lets assume you want to set the value of the third particle of the first grid to 2.7182: (you should insert this code in the place I commented as `/* Assign, modify, read or copy values from the array of pointers here */`)

```
grids[0]->particles[2].value = 2.7182;
```

And this can be read, from left to right, as: "From the array of pointers `grids`, get the element with index 0 (the first pointer to a `Grid` structure). Access its structure member `particles`, which is  a pointer. Treat that pointer as an array and get the element with index 2 (the third `Particle` structure). Access its member `value` and assign to it the value 2.7182"

You could then do something like copy one particle to another:

```
grids[1]->particles[1] = grids[0]->particles[2];
```

Here are some links to better understand pointers, arrays and structs. Practice and experimentation is the best way to deal with them:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Pointers
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Arrays
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Structures

---

## Update

> I realized that what I should be doing is use the inparticles pointer to point to multiple particles in the same grid pointer

> I need to use a separate array of pointers to particles. The array inside the grid structure is only to point to a subset of particles.

Objective: "Use the inparticles pointer to point to a subset of multiple (*sequential or non-sequential?*) particles (which are being managed somewhere else)".

If you want the sequential solution you could use a pointer, representing a pointer to the *base address* (or *offset*, if you want only a subset) of an array (this is, a pointer to an array). This has the advantage of not needing you to allocate extra memory for every single pointer (since only the base address is necessary), but it has the disadvantage that you can only access particles that are next to each other.

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int width;
    int height;
    Particle *subparticles; //Represents a pointer to an array subset
}Grid;
```

```
    /*...*/

    grids[0]->subparticles = &particles[0];
    grids[1]->subparticles = &particles[1];

    printf("%f equals %f", grids[0]->subparticles[1].value, grids[1]->subparticles[0].value);

    /*...*/
```

However, If you want the non-sequential solution, you could use a double pointer (representing an array of pointers) while having to manually allocate memory for the array. This provides you with more flexibility, but comes at the price of memory allocation overhead.

```
typedef struct
{
    /*...other members...*/
    Particle **subparticles;
}Grid;

Grid *createGrid(int subparticlesCount)
{
    Grid *result = malloc(sizeof(Grid));
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while allocating memory for the grid structure!\n");
        exit(1);
    }else
    {
        result->subparticles = malloc(sizeof(Particle *) * subparticlesCount);
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
    /*...*/

    grids[0]->subparticles[0] = &particles[1];
    grids[0]->subparticles[1] = &particles[5];
    grids[0]->subparticles[2] = &particles[3];
    grids[1]->subparticles[0] = &particles[3];

    printf("%f equals %f", grids[0]->subparticles[2]->value, grids[1]->subparticles[0]->value);

    /*...*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your write up. However, I need to use a separate array of pointers to particles. The array inside the grid structure is only to point to a subset of particles.

Comment: @YaserBaqi I misunderstood, answer is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a field which is a pointer (to some array), if that field is the *last* of its `struct`, you could make it a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). So declare

```
typedef struct {
  int m;
  int n;
  unsigned count;
  particle_t inparticle_arr[];    // flexible array of count elements
} grid_t;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108) for an example and details, and a C standard (like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.7.2.1) or [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct).

In *some* cases, avoiding pointers and indirection may *slightly* speedup your code (because of the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)). Flexible array members also avoid an extra `free` for that internal flexible array.

For debugging and avoiding [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), compile your C code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (or the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question and subsequent comments, what I understood is that you want to create a grid which should contain a pointer to an **array of pointers** (i.e multiple pointers) in which each pointer points to struct of type `particle_t`.

On the basis of this understanding, I have modified your original code and have provided appropriate comments in the code itself wherever necessary. However, if I have misinterpreted your question then let me know, I will update the answer accordingly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    double vx;
} particle_t;

typedef struct {
    int m;
    int n;
    particle_t **inparticles;    // inparticles is a pointer to (array of 
                                // pointers to inparticle)
    int size; // max number of particles in the grid
} grid_t;

grid_t *new_grid(int size) { // A helper function to create grid
    grid_t *grid = (grid_t*)malloc(sizeof(grid_t));
    grid->inparticles = (particle_t**)malloc(sizeof(particle_t*));

    if(grid == NULL || grid->inparticles == NULL) return NULL;

    grid->size = size;

    for(int i=0;i<size;++i) {
        grid->inparticles[i] = (particle_t*)malloc(sizeof(particle_t));
        if(grid->inparticles[i] == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return grid;
}
int main() {
    particle_t *particles = (particle_t*)malloc( 3 * sizeof(particle_t) );

    //create a new grid which can contain multiple particles --- Use a for 
    //loop for creating multiple grids 
    grid_t *grid = new_grid(3);

    if( particles==NULL || grid==NULL ){
        puts("Unable to allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    grid->inparticles[0] = &particles[0];
    grid->inparticles[1] = &particles[1];
    grid->inparticles[2] = &particles[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When things get complicated, divide and conquer is the best approach.

Create an array of structs of type `particle_t` on the heap:

```
particle_t* partAddr = malloc(sizeof(particle_t) * numParticles);
```

Create an array of structs of type `grid_t` on the heap:

```
grid_t* gridAddr = malloc(sizeof(grid_t) * numGrids);
```

Make one element of the array of type `grid_t` to point to an allocated element of type `particle_t`:

```
gridAddr[n].inparticles = partAddr;
```

Assign a value to the vx field of the first element of the array of the first element of the grid:

```
grid[0].inparticles[0].vx= 3;
```

---

Everything together  (where the number of particles can vary):

```
// Define the size of each array of particles
#define ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_A 5
#define ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_B 2
#define ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_C 7

// Create indexes and size to avoid out of boundaries accesses
enum GRID_PARTICLES {
    ARRAY_PARTICLE_0 = 0,
    ARRAY_PARTICLE_1,
    ARRAY_PARTICLE_2,
    GRID_SIZE
};

typedef struct {
    double vx;
} particle_t;

typedef struct {
    particle_t *inparticles;
} grid_t;

particle_t* allocateArrayOfParticles(int numParticles) {
    particle_t* partAddr = malloc(sizeof(particle_t) * numParticles);
    if(partAddr == NULL){
        // trigger an error
    }
    return partAddr;
}

void deallocateArrayOfParticles(particle_t *partAddr) {
    free(partAddr);
}


grid_t* allocateGridOfParticles(int numGrids) {
    grid_t* gridAddr = malloc(sizeof(grid_t) * numGrids);
    if(gridAddr == NULL) {
        // trigger an error
    }
    return gridAddr;
}

void deallocateGridOfParticles(grid_t *gridAddr) {
    free(gridAddr);
}

int main(void) {    
    grid_t *grid = allocateGridOfParticles(GRID_SIZE);
    particle_t *partA = allocateArrayOfParticles(ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_A);
    particle_t *partB = allocateArrayOfParticles(ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_B);
    particle_t *partC = allocateArrayOfParticles(ELEMENTS_ARRAY_PARTICLE_C);
  
    grid[ARRAY_PARTICLE_0].inparticles = partA;
    grid[ARRAY_PARTICLE_1].inparticles = partB;
    grid[ARRAY_PARTICLE_2].inparticles = partC;

    deallocateArrayOfParticles(partA);
    deallocateArrayOfParticles(partB);
    deallocateArrayOfParticles(partC);
    deallocateGridOfParticles(grid);
}
```