# Accessing static global array from another file via function argument

Tags: c, arrays, static, segmentation-fault, arguments

Getting segmentation fault while accessing the data from a static global array from another file; the pointer was passed as a function argument. The memory address shows the same from both file.

In file1.c

```
static long long T[12][16];
...
/* inside some function*/
  printf(" %p \n", T); // Check the address
  func_access_static(T);
...
```

In file2.c

```
void func_access_static(long long** t)
{
  printf(" %p \n", t); // shows the same address
  printf(" %lld \n", t[0][0]); // gives segmentation fault
}
```

Am I trying to do something that can't be done? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use the correct function signature. `long[][]` and `long**` differ.

Comment: How does that even compile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass multiple-dimensional array to a function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822382/pass-multiple-dimensional-array-to-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. @RSahu Thanks for that post. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**` is not the same thing than an array.

Declare your function

```
void func_access_static(long long t[][16])
```

or

```
void func_access_static(long long (*t)[16])
```

This is what a 2 dimensional array `int t[2][3]` looks like in memory

```
                              t
              t[0]                          t[1]
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| t[0][0] | t[0][1] | t[0][2] | t[1][0] | t[1][1] | t[1][2] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
     Contiguous memory cells  of int type
```

This is what a pointer on pointer `int **` looks like in memory

```
  pointer           pointer   pointer
+---------+       +---------+---------+       
|   p     |  -->  | p[0]    |  p[1]   |
+---------+       +---------+---------+      
                       |         |            Somewhere in memory
                       |         |           +---------+---------+---------+
                       |         \---------->| p[1][0] | p[1][1] | p[1][2] |
                       |                     +---------+---------+---------+
                       |
                       |                      Somewhere else in memory
                       |                     +---------+---------+---------+
                       \-------------------->| p[0][0] | p[0][1] | p[0][2] |
                                             +---------+---------+---------+
```

To access the content it's the same syntax but the operation is quite different.