# Dynamically-allocated two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I've got stuck on compiling two-dimensional array in C using malloc();

Trying to compile my code in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 I keep getting error 'a value of type "int **" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"'

Here is my code:

```
  int main() {
    int lines = 0;
    int **cord;

    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) return 0;

    fscanf(f, "%d", &lines);
    printf("%d", lines);

    *cord = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < lines; ++i)
    {
        cord[i] = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        fscanf(f, "%d", cord[i][0]);
        fscanf(f, "%d", cord[i][1]);
    }
    i = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone point me what is wrong there?

Comment: In C don't cast the result of `malloc` but *always test* against failure of `malloc`; also enable all warnings & debug info.

Comment: This is not a 2D array but only an emulation of it. You can define  and initialize your array with a single call to `malloc` as `int (*cord)[2] = malloc(2*lines*sizeof(int));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*cord = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));
```

The variable `cord` has type `int **`, so the *expression* `*cord` has type `int *`.  You're casting the result of `malloc` to `int **`.  Thus, you're attempting to assign a value of type `int **` to an expression of type `int *`, which is an error.  That line should be written as

```
cord = malloc( lines * sizeof *cord ); // note no cast, operand of sizeof
```

Style note - whitespace is your friend.  Use it.  Your eyes aren't going to be 20 years old forever.

If the number of columns is known at compile time (as it appears to be in this case), you can do a one-step allocation:

```
int (*cord)[2];
...
cord = malloc( lines * sizeof *cord ); 
if ( cord )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < lines; i++ )
  {
    fscanf( f, "%d", &cord[i][0] );
    fscanf( f, "%d", &cord[i][1] );
  }
  ...
  free( cord );
}
else
  // handle allocation failure
```

The variable`cord` has type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`", so the expression `*cord` has type "2-element array of `int`".  `sizeof *cord` gives us the number of bytes required for each subarray, so `lines * sizeof *cord` gives us the total number of bytes required for the whole 2D array.

Advantages - single-step allocation (meaning single-step deallocation), and all the rows in the array are contiguous.

Disadvantages - May fail for *very large* arrays if memory is sufficiently fragmented, requires that you know the number of columns at compile time or that your compiler supports variable-length arrays (which were introduced in C99 and are optional as of C2011).

In general, your `malloc` statements should be written as

```
T *ptr = malloc( N * sizeof *ptr ); // calloc( N, sizeof *ptr )
```

or

```
T *ptr = NULL;
...
ptr = malloc( N * sizeof *ptr );  // calloc( N, sizeof *ptr );
```

C doesn't require you to cast the result of `malloc/calloc`<sup>1</sup>. C++ *does* require it since it doesn't allow implicit conversion of `void` pointers, but if you're writing C++ you should be using `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

---

<sup>1.  As of the 1989 standard, anyway; prior to C89, `malloc` and `calloc` returned `char *` instead of `void *`, so for pre-C89 compilers the cast *was* required.  MSVC supports the C89 standard, so you don't need the cast</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First, **DO NOT** cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Regarding the error, in your code, first you need to allocate memory to `cord`, then to `cord[i]` (or `*cord`).

Instead of using

`*cord = malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));`,

use

`cord = malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));`

Also, add a `NULL` check for success of `malloc()`, like

```
if (!cord)   //also for cord[i]
{
    //print error and return / exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
*cord = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));
```

is wrong, you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer `cord`. Please code

```
cord = malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));
if (!cord) { perror("malloc cord"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Never forget to test against failure of `malloc` (you should also test it when assigning `cord[i]`)

BTW, you should enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. If using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have been warned for the first mistake.

Also, if you want a matrix in C, better use a one-dimensional array to represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
*cord = (int**)malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));
```

to

```
cord = malloc(lines*sizeof(int*));
```

Also, you are not allocating a 2D array, but rather a pointer-based lookup table. To allocate a real 2D array, do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c).