# array by malloc on function lu decomposition

Tags: c, matrix

im trying to do lu decomposition using nxn matrix typed by scanf but having errors on using nxn matrix for gauss function i what to know the ways to use array by malloc on function.
the way to use matrix[x][y] on gauss fucntion is the point

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void gauss(int n,double **matrix,double **L,double **U,double **ans);

int main(void)

{

    int i, n;//
    int x, y;//line x,row y
    double **matrix; //define matrix[x][y]
    double **L;
    double **U;
    double **ans;

    printf("nxn matrix type n.\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);



    matrix = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
    if (matrix == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
        if (matrix[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    } //build matrix[x][y(size of x)] structure

    L = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
    if (L == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        L[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
        if (L[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    } //build L[x][y(size of x)] structure

    U = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
   if (U == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
   for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
       U[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
       if (U[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }

   } //build U[x][y(size of x)] structure

   ans = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
   if (ans == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
   for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
       ans[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
       if (ans[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }

   } //build ans[x][y(size of x)] structure

    printf("type the number of matrix \n");
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++){
            printf("line %d  x%d number : ", x + 1, y + 1);
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[x][y]);
        }
    }
/*
for (x = 0; x < n; x++){
    for (y = 0; y < n; y++){
        printf("line %d  x%d number : %.2lf \n", x + 1, y + 1,matrix[x][y]);

    }
}
*/
gauss(n,matrix,L,U,ans);

/*

for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix);//free matrix

for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
   free(L[i]);
}
free(L);//free L

for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
free(U[i]);
}
free(U);//free U
*/

return 0;

}

void gauss(int n,double **matrix,double **L,double **U,double **ans){
int x,y;
for(x=0;x<=n;x++){
    if(matrix[x][0]!=0){
        for(y=0;y<=n;y++){
            matrix[x][y]=matrix[x][y]/matrix[x][0];
            L[x][0]=matrix[x][0];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get ? That apart, you alloc `sizeof(float)` when your variables are declared `double`, there's probably a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: i can't call out matrix on gauss function it stops when gauss is called :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c

Answer (score 2):

1. You allocate memory for `float` matrix, but then use it as `double`, since sizes of `float` and `double` are different you got errors.
2. The correct way to go through matrix rows and colums is like this

   ```
   for(x=0; x<n; x++){
       ...
   }
   ```

   but you wrote

   ```
   for(x=0;x<=n;x++){
       ....
   }
   ```

   so you tried to access non-existing row with index `n` (but last row has index `n-1`).

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void gauss(int n, float **matrix, float **L, float **U, float **ans);

int main(void)
{

    int i, n;//
    int x, y;//line x,row y
    float **matrix; //define matrix[x][y]
    float **L;
    float **U;
    float **ans;

    printf("nxn matrix type n.\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    matrix = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
    if (matrix == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
        if (matrix[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    } //build matrix[x][y(size of x)] structure

    L = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
    if (L == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        L[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
        if (L[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
    } //build L[x][y(size of x)] structure

    U = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
   if (U == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
   for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
       U[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
       if (U[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }

   } //build U[x][y(size of x)] structure

   ans = malloc(sizeof(float *) * n); // int* number x primary structure
   if (ans == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
   for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
       ans[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
       if (ans[i] == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }

   } //build ans[x][y(size of x)] structure

    printf("type the number of matrix \n");
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++){
            printf("line %d  x%d number : ", x + 1, y + 1);
            scanf("%f", &matrix[x][y]);
        }
    }

    gauss(n,matrix,L,U,ans);

    return 0;
}

void gauss(int n, float **matrix, float **L, float **U, float **ans) {
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<n;x++){
        if(matrix[x][0]!=0){
            for(y=0;y<n;y++){
                matrix[x][y]=matrix[x][y]/matrix[x][0];
                L[x][0]=matrix[x][0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "throw" is a verb, did you mean, "go trough" or "go through"? (+1 anyway)

Comment: I wonder if someone has thought about an editor mode "english for foreigners and Americans" that automatically highlights problematic words like "tail <-> tale", "passed <-> past", "there <-> their <-> they're", "your <-> you're" etc.

Answer (score 1):

For complete analysis, see answer of NicolayKondratyev. One small optimization:

One should avoid to call "malloc" too often, the minimal variant for a nxn matrix is

```
matrix = malloc( n*sizeof(*matrix)*n + n*n*sizeof(**matrix) ); 
if (matrix == NULL){ printf("malloc failed\n"); exit(1); }
matrix[0] = (float*)(matrix + n);
for(k=1; k<n; k++) matrix[k] = matrix[k-1] + n
```

---

From Lundin's link in comment to question https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462760/3088138 , since C99 the shortest and most economic matrix allocation is

```
float (*matrix)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float[n][n]));
```

which avoids the layered pointer-to-pointer structure.

Comment: Please don't recommend to cast the result of malloc in C. It wasn't there in the original code.

Comment: @Lundin: Is there a deeper reason? It may be obvious and automatic in many cases, here however a memory area is spliced into two arrays of different type, the explicit casts at least increase readability.

Comment: See the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Ok. Casting malloc results may hide programming errors. Does this also apply to the second cast?

Comment: Yes. There is never a reason to cast the result of malloc in C.