# Segmentation fault while taking multidimensional array elements

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, scanf

When i run the following code i got an error;

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00007ffff7a74402 in __GI__IO_vfscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install
>   glibc-2.17-78.el7.x86_64

i run my code using gcc warnings enable(-Wall) and debug it step by step. The error is in the line for getting multi-dimensional array elements. When i reach at the step for grades[1][2], it says cannot access memory at address 0x00007ffff7a74402. What is the wrong in the code?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    //_________Prototypes________//

    int calcHighest(int grades[][4],int);
    int calcLowest(int grades[][4],int);
    int calcAverage(int grades[][4],int);

    int main (void){

      int funcSelection,nbOfStudent;
      int grades[nbOfStudent][4];
      int i,j;

      scanf("%d",&funcSelection);

     //check is one 1,2,3 and a number
      if(funcSelection <= 0 || funcSelection > 3){
        printf("Invalid Input.Please enter 1,2 or 3\n");
          return 1;
      }

      scanf("%d",&nbOfStudent);
     //check if it is positive and a number
      if(nbOfStudent <= 0){
        printf("Please enter a non-negative number\n");
         return 1;
      }

      for(i = 0;i < nbOfStudent;i++){
         for(j =0;j<4;j++){
           scanf("%d",&grades[i][j]);
         }
       }

      for(i = 0;i < nbOfStudent;i++){
         for(j =0;j<4;j++){
           scanf("%d",&grades[i][j]);
         }
       }

      if(funcSelection == 1){

        printf("%d\n",calcLowest(grades,nbOfStudent));
      }else if(funcSelection == 2){
        printf("%d\n",calcHighest(grades,nbOfStudent));
      }else{
        printf("%d\n",calcAverage(grades,nbOfStudent));
      }
      return 0;

    }
```

Comment: `int grades[nbOfStudent][4];` as yourself what the value of `nbOfStudent` is *when that declaration is encountered*. Hint: `scanf`-ing that variable later doesn't change what came before.

Comment: Then,how can i create array with dynamic size?

Comment: see my question: [How can I work with dynamically-allocated arbitrary-dimensional arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023867/how-can-i-work-with-dynamically-allocated-arbitrary-dimensional-arrays) My answer shows a 'clever' way. The highest-voted answer shows a typical C99 way.

Answer (score 4):

This is where the problem lies:

```
int funcSelection,nbOfStudent;
int grades[nbOfStudent][4];
```

Think what's the value of `nbOfStudent` is when `grades` is defined. Since `nbOfStudent` is uninitialized, anything could be its value and using an uninitialized variable invokes Undefined Behavior.

Fix the problem by moving

```
int grades[nbOfStudent][4];
```

after

```
scanf("%d",&nbOfStudent);
//check if it is positive and a number
if(nbOfStudent <= 0){
  printf("Please enter a non-negative number\n");
 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int funcSelection,nbOfStudent;
      int grades[nbOfStudent][4]; //problem leads to undefined behaviour
      int i,j;
```

`nbofStudent` doesnot contain any value its a garbage vale and its lead to undefined behaviour.

Solution:

populate the value `nbofStudent` before defining an array.
in your case `scanf` for `nbofStudent` before declaring an array and check for the validity of the variable.

```
scanf("%d",&nbOfStudent);
     //check if it is positive and a number
      if(nbOfStudent <= 0){
        printf("Please enter a non-negative number\n");
         return 1;
      }
```

Variable should be defined after these instructions. so silly to mention statements execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains several errors and oversights, including:

1. fails to prompt user for number of students
2. contains 'magic' numbers like 3 and 4
3. fails to prompt user for grades for each student
4. fails to prompt user for which 'function' to be performed
5. uses `int` for values that can only be positive

Here is my proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define NUM_GRADES (4)
#define MAX_FUNC   (3)

//_________Prototypes________//
int calcHighest(int grades[][ NUM_GRADES ], size_t);
int calcLowest( int grades[][ NUM_GRADES ], size_t);
int calcAverage(int grades[][ NUM_GRADES ], size_t);

int main (void)
{

    printf( "Enter number of Students: ");
    size_t nbOfStudent;
    if( 1 != scanf("%lu",&nbOfStudent) )
    { // then scanf for number of students failed
        perror( "scanf for number students failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    //only declare array 'grades[][]' after knowing number of students
    int grades[nbOfStudent][ NUM_GRADES ];

    printf( "Enter %d grades for each of the %lu students: ", NUM_GRADES, nbOfStudent);
    for(size_t i = 0;i < nbOfStudent;i++)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j<NUM_GRADES; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&grades[i][j]);
        }
    }


    printf( "1: calculate lowest student grade\n");
    printf( "2: calculate highest student grade\n");
    printf( "3: calculate average student grade\n");
    printf( "Enter Selection: ");
    size_t funcSelection;
    scanf("%lu",&funcSelection);
    if( 1 != scanf("%lu",&funcSelection) )
    { // then scanf for function selection failed
        perror( "scanf for function selection failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    switch( funcSelection )
    {
        case 1:
            printf("%d\n",calcLowest(grades,nbOfStudent));
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("%d\n",calcHighest(grades,nbOfStudent));
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("%d\n",calcAverage(grades,nbOfStudent));
            break;

        case 0: // fall through
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input.Please enter 1,2 or 3\n");
            break;
    } // end switch

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```