# function to modify 2d array to add row an a column using realloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

Whats wrong with this function, which is expected to add a row and a column to given 2D array? Matrix is symmetric.

```
void updateMatrix(double ***mat, int size, double *vec)
{ // mat is sizeXsize matrix, length of vec is size+1
    *mat = (double**)realloc(*mat, (size + 1)*sizeof(double*));
    (*mat)[size] = (double*)malloc((size + 1)*sizeof(double));

    for(int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++) {
        (*mat)[size][i] = vec[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        (*mat)[i] = (double*)realloc((*mat)[i], (size + 1)*sizeof(double));
        (*mat)[i][size] = vec[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, what problems are you experiencing? Do you have build errors? Run-time errors or crashes? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: Also, don't reassign the pointer you're reallocating to itself, think about what would happen if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`.

Comment: Then run in a debugger to locate the crash in your code. And step through the code you think is faulty to see that it does exactly what you think it is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tried that.. still after few calls, this particular function segmentation fault.

Comment: `vec` is of `size` or `size+1` ? Your for loops use both.

Comment: *Where* does it crash? On which line?

Comment: The problem could be in the calling function. If size increases by more 1 on successive calls you will end up with rows containing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: This isn't a 2D array, it is a lookup table. Arrays are allocated in adjacent memory cells. Is there any particular reason why you like to have your data fragmented all over the heap? If not, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c).

Comment: fails at first line...
valgrind says - Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Comment: This part of the code seems right...except that the advice of @JoachimPileborg should be followed. See [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) for a correct way to use `realloc()` and check if it returns `NULL`. Moreover, it is stated that the first argument of `realloc()` should be a `Pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc.
Alternatively, this can be a null pointer, in which case a new block is allocated (as if malloc was called).`. Is `*mat` set to `NULL`, or a return of `malloc` the first time a row/col is created ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The above code is correct (at least logically). Issue was in the calling part, where I was sending the copy of A (2d pointer) to the caller of this function instead of &A.

Comment: @PalashKumar Please answer the question( you can answer your own questions ), delete it, or flag it for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Your realloc is returning NULL in the second for loop..
I'm trying to figure out why.

Have you allocated everything before hand? Because chances are you might be passing a non NULL and non malloced pointer to realloc. And that is forbidden/will cause errors

Or, as says @MichaelDorgan , you could just be passing a gigantic size to your function but i sincereley hope you are not trying to allocate a few Go for an array. Otherwise i'm curious as to its use.

Comment: Or he just might be passing in a gigantic size.  Proper if / handling code around allocations would answer some of his questions for sure.