# How to fix unstable free() call on a ragged matrix inside a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm creating a map with n * m dimensions, that should be gotten from a file input. Each position of the map matters for distance counting. In the whole execution cycle I go through 4 malloc() calls, however I can't match them with 4 free() calls or the execution might or might not finish and I can't understand why.

Here's the main call:

```
int main()
{
    map_t newMap;
    newMap = map_create(30, 30);

    //there's some test calls that I'm ommiting as they simply work and don't matter

    map_destroy(newMap);
    return 0;
}
```

the map_t as I understand and as I want is a pointer to a structure, it's defined on a header file as following:

```
typedef struct map *map_t;
```

it's implementation is on the corresponding .c file for matters of encapsulation. Here's the implementation and the important functions for the case:

```
struct map{
    position_t **positions;
    int lines, columns;
};

map_t map_create(int n, int m)
{
    map_t newMap = malloc(sizeof(map_t));

    newMap->lines = n;
    newMap->columns = m;

    newMap->positions = malloc(n * sizeof(position_t*));
    int i;
    int k;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        newMap->positions[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(position_t));
        for(k = 0; k < m; ++k)
        {
            newMap->positions[i][k] = position_create();
        }
    }

    return newMap;
}

void map_destroy(map_t map_p)
{
    int i, k;
    int n = map_p->lines;
    int m = map_p->columns;
    for(i=0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(k=0; k < m; ++k)
        {
            position_destroy(map_p->positions[i][k]);
        }
        free(map_p->positions[i]);
    }

    free(map_p->positions);

    free(map_p);
}
```

For matters of completeness, here's the position struct specific code, it follows the same idea of the map struct.

```
typedef struct position *position_t; //this is on the .h, the rest is on the .c file

struct position{
    int has_treasure;
    int times_visited;
};

position_t position_create()
{
    position_t newPosition = malloc(sizeof *newPosition);
    newPosition->has_treasure = YES;
    newPosition->times_visited = 0;

    return newPosition;
}

void position_destroy(position_t position_p)
{
    free(position_p);
}
```

I've identified which free calls are causing the problem, I just can't understand why. If I comment these 2 lines:

```
free(map_p->positions);
free(map_p);
```

everything works fine. I've seen different ways to allocate the initial memory such as this one - [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c?lq=1) - but even with the various solutions found there I keep getting the same unstability.

It might be extremely simple and I'm just overlooking something, been on this for 5 days now, as much I hate to borrow anyone's time on this mess, even if I have to implement a different solution I'd like to at least understand what's wrong.

Code isn't producing any warnings with -Wall -g  -c and if I add -pedantic I just get complaints about comments.

Cheers in advance

EDIT: Changed `position_t newPosition = malloc(sizeof(position_t));` to `position_t newPosition = malloc(sizeof *newPosition);`
behaviour is still the same

EDIT2: did the exact type of change on the map_t malloc, problem solved, the whole time I thought the problem was on the `**positions`

Comment: Why not use a 2D array?

Comment: Code like `position_t newPosition = malloc(sizeof(position_t));` will allocate the size of a pointer and not the strcuct you clearly are expecting ....

Comment: I see no use of `position_t` being a pointer. Please don't be a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: It say `typedef struct position *position_t;`   so position_t is a pointer

Comment: Regarding the comment from @Soren, this is why most experienced programmers avoid against creating type-aliases of pointers. When even you, who written the code and should know that e,g, `map_t` is a pointer, have trouble distinguishing the types and their pointers, it should make you think a little. Better use explicit pointer declarations when needed.

Comment: @Soren but if that's the problem, wouldn't it give the problems related to the position struct instead of the map struct?

Comment: @Kirag -- you are writing in memory you have not allocated (your malloc is too small) so the entire program has undefined behavior -- who know what will happen, and how -- this may not be the exact problem you asked about which is why I didn't put it as an answer -- but fix you malloc size problems first

Comment: The `position` structure has two `int` variables, each probably 32 bits, making the whole structure 64 bits in size. Which incidentally is the size of a pointer on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did the typedef on purpose tho after this https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/06/03/encapsulation-in-c/ although I understand your point, and I know it is a pointer but has the _t suffix on the name, that might be a bad naming for others to read tho. In the end tho I can iterate and change the positions without problems, it's the last 2 free() calls that cause instability, can it be related? EDIT: just read your last reponse, does make sense then. Thank you!!

Comment: By the way, a quick tip on how to always get the right size for simple allocations: `position_t newPosition = malloc(sizeof *newPosition);` Note the dereferencing of `newPosition` in the call to `malloc`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I should've tried that before, changed it but it keeps randomly crashing on the last 2 free calls, I'm starting to feel ashamed by this

Comment: @Kirag -- you also have the same problem with your map_t as it is also defined as a pointer

Comment: @Soren totally right, it's working without any problems at all now. I really feel ashamed, but more importantly I feel grateful, thank you both, I can finally sleep

Answer (score 0):

The first `malloc(sizeof(map_t));` allocates only space for a pointer. You need to use `malloc(sizeof(*map_t));`.

But you already found that now, I see.