# Dynamic array cleanup when malloc returns null

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, null, malloc

I am wondering what is the best way to clean up memory which was already allocated during the failed creation of 2D array.

```
int** a = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
    a[i] = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
    free(a[i]);

free(a);
```

The sample code above should work like a charm. However `malloc` can return `null` and when it will the code above will not handle the problem. How can we protect such case?

Let's say `(int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int))` returned `null` for `i = 3`. We already have allocated space for `int** a` and `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]`.

Here is my current approach. Ugly and not sure if correct. This is why I am asking you for help.

```
int rows;
int columns;
scanf("%d", &rows);
scanf("%d", &columns);

int** a = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
if (!a)
{
    printf("Cannot allocate enough space."); // nothing to clean up here
    return 1; // to make example easier
}

int i;
bool arrayCreated = true;

for (i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
{
    int* tmp = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    if (!tmp) // malloc returned null
    {
        arrayCreated = false; // let's mark that we need to do some cleanup
        break;
    }
    a[i] = tmp;
}

if (!arrayCreated) // creation failed, clean up is needed
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        free(a[j]);
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
        free(a[i]);
}

free(a);
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It would be great to see a full example. Do you mind sharing?

Comment: Lots of questions, better to post for one language at a time.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I love containers and smart pointers and I am using them all the time. I was just wondering how it was done in the past.

Comment: [Like This](http://ideone.com/I5283H) ?

Comment: Why is there a mixture of C++'s `delete` and C's `free`... ? *frowns*

Comment: @dptd Don't mix `new`, `malloc` and `free`. That's a strong rule.

Comment: @dptd Also elaborate in your question please, why you think these comments and answers are actually ***useless***? These are the idiomatic ways to deal with memory allocation. I you want something different choose another programming language,

Comment: Your `calloc` allocations are `sizeof(int*)` times too large.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This answers are useless for me because I know how to work with containers and smart pointers. What I do not know is how to clean up memory when error occurs during dynamic allocation in the loop. I pointed it few times already but somehow people keep saying the same thing again and again.

Comment: Please write one question for c and one for c++

Comment: @MikeMB I will when I will be able to. Currently I cannot ask new questions because this one has too many negative votes.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

As you have different functions used to allocate memory, you'll need to call their counterpart deallocation functions accordingly:

- `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` need to be deallocated with a call to `free()`
- `X* x = new X();` needs to be deallocated with `delete x;`
- `X** x = new X[10];` needs to be deallocated with `delete[] x;`

---

The idiomatic way in c++ is to use either a container

- `std::vector<X> x;`

or a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) like

- `std::unique_ptr<X> x = std::make_unique<X>();`

to redeem you from caring about the necessary bookkeeping to balance allocation/deallocation operations correctly.

---

> Please notice that this is a theoretical question about error handling in such, specific cases. I want to highlight that first two cases are for C, not C++.

There's no standard error handling defined if you're using the wrong pairs of dynamic memory de-/allocation functions.

As mentioned above they need to pair like described. Anything else calls undefined behavior.

Comment: @t0mm13b Didn't I say so?

Comment: Are you sure one call to `free()` is enough when allocating memory with `malloc()` or `calloc()` in the loop? If `null pointer` will be returned during the second iteration how should you clean up memory allocated so far?

Comment: @dptd Each call to `malloc()` or `calloc()` needs a corresponding call to `free()` of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
int** b = (int**)calloc(sizeof(int*) * rows, sizeof(int*));
```

This is not correct, the first parameter of `calloc` is "number of elements to allocate".

should be

```
int** b = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*)); /* No need to cast in C */
```

> What is the safe way for creating multidimensional arrays in C and C++
>   for such scenarios?

In C (in order to avoid segmentation) a real 2D dynamic array should be declared as

```
int (*arr)[columns]; /* A pointer to an array of n ints */
```

and (m)allocated using

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(int [rows][columns]));
```

or

```
arr = calloc(rows, sizeof(int[columns]));
```

In this way a single call to `free(arr);` is enough.

Comment: **In C a real 2D array should be declared as...** You didn't explain why.

Comment: @Michi, the code provided by OP is a segmented pointer-to-pointer thing, this is explained in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c

Comment: I though that it will be good for the OP and new comers in/to **C** :)

Comment: @AlterMann In `int (*arr)[columns];` can `columns` value be provided during the runtime or maybe this value must be known at the compile time?

Comment: Yes, when provided at runtime it is called VLA [Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about C, but C++; delete[] should suffice.

Comment: FYI there is no `delete` in C