# Dynamically allocate Matrix using typedef

Tags: c

I already have an idea on how to `malloc` a matrix if it were an `int**`. **But using a `typedef`**, I think  have an idea but I'm not so sure.

```
typedef int LabeledAdjMatrix[SIZE][SIZE];
```

Do I do it like this?

```
APSP = (APSPMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(APSPMatrix));
```

But when I access it I'm gonna have to use `*APSP[0][0]` and I have no idea how to use this in `memset`/`memcpy`.

Is there a proper way of doing this? Both in dynamically allocating and in accessing.

Comment: what is `APSPMatrix` ? Did you mean `LabeledAdjMatrix` ?

Comment: Oh shoot yes. There was a `#define APSPMatrix LabeledAdjMatrix`. I forgot to include that woops.

Comment: `*APSP[0][0]` --> `(*APSP)[0][0]`

Comment: @BoredChinese: I wrote a specific [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39952606/3545273) for your question in the duplicate... Hope it helps

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you for the answer! I can't reply directly to that post of yours since my reputation is below 50 haha.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to not use array typedefs, they make the code harder to read as it is less apparent when array-pointer decay is or isn't happening.

If you want to allocate a contiguous array you can write:

```
int (*APSP)[SIZE] = malloc( sizeof(int[SIZE][SIZE]) );
```

and then access it as `APSP[0][0]`.

Your post talks about "malloc as if it were `int **`", by which I assume you mean you want separate allocations for each rows... but then you would write `int **APSP` and write a loop to allocate each row,  it is really nothing to do with `[SIZE][SIZE]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's my professor who made the typedef and not me and I'm supposed to use it. :-(