# Problems using malloc, structs and probably parameters

Tags: c, struct, utf-8, segmentation-fault, malloc

EDIT: OK, I hear you guys, I've isolated the part of my code that's giving me problems, compiled it and made sure that it still gave me the same results, here it goes:
Like before, the segfault appears after the first instance of the for loop on
strcpy(replace[j]->utf8, strtok(data, "\t")); Thanks again!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define max_chars 45
#define max_UTF 5
#define max_ASCII 7
#define max_word_length 30
#define max_line_length 70
#define max_texto_line 5000

typedef struct {
char utf8[max_UTF];
char ascii_seq[max_ASCII];
int count;
} Replac; 


void getTable(FILE *f, char inputfile[],Replac **replace){
    char data[max_line_length];
    int j;
    f = fopen( inputfile, "r" );
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file %s!\n",inputfile);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fgets(data,sizeof data,f);
    for(j=0 ; strcmp(data,"\n") ; fgets(data,sizeof data,f), j++){  
        if (feof(f)) {                                      
            break;
        }
        strcpy(replace[j]->utf8, strtok(data, "\t"));                   
        strcpy(replace[j]->ascii_seq, strtok(NULL, "\n"));
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    Replac *replace=malloc(max_chars * sizeof(Replac));
    FILE *fpr,*f,*fpw;
    int carprocess = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_PT.UTF-8");
    setlocale(LC_COLLATE,"pt_PT.UTF-8");
    
    
    getTable(f,argv[1],&replace);
}
```

The text file that I'm copying the character from is formated something like this

```
UTFCHAR \tab asciichar
```

ex

```
Á   'A
```

END EDIT

## -#-##-###-####-####+#####+####p

So I'm a beginner using C, and I've tried all I could think of, this seems like a pretty straight forward thing to do, but since I'm having such trouble clearly shows I have some gap in my knowledge...

I wont bother you with the full code since it is working perfectly, it's just that I wanted to do things differently and that's when the trouble started.

In short I'm doing a program that collects a set of chars of UTF8 type, and their ascii replacement, and stores them in a struct such as

```
 typedef struct {
char utf8[max_UTF];
char ascii_seq[mac_ASCII];
} Replac;
```

then in main I did the malloc like this

```
Replac *replace=malloc(max_chars * sizeof(Replac));
```

If my thought process is correct, this would create a block of available memory to which *replace is pointing to the starting address.

Then I made a function that scans a few UTF8 chars and their replacement and stores them in the struct, something like

```
void getTable(FILE *f, char inputfile[],Replac **replace)
```

now, following the debugger, it seems that I'm creating new variable replace of the type Replace** that's on a completely different address, but inside that address is stored the value to the original malloced struct that I passed through the param.

After that I do a

```
strcpy(replace[0]->utf8, something I got from the table);
```

following the debugger and searching through the memory adresses, I see that the first time I do this, the first position of the malloc struct is indeed filled with the right data.

followed by

```
strcpy(replace[0]->ascii_seq, corresponding ascii sequence to the previous UTF8 char);
```

and that fills the next memory position in the memory block.

So I get something like while debugging on my variables watch

address replace = (Replac **) 0xbf8104fc that contains 0x0878a008

address *replace = (Replac *) 0x0878a008 that contains the whole struct
so inside the address 0x0878a008 I get the data of the utf8 char and then at the address 0x0878a00d I get the ascii seq.

The problem in on the next instance of the loop, when it's time to

```
strcpy(replace[1]->utf8, something I got from the table);
```

I get a segmentation fault after that instruction.

So what do you guys think? Am I approaching things correctly, and I'm getting screwed over by syntax or something like that, or is it the base of my knowledge flawed?

Thanks, and a late happy holidays!

Comment: Without true code, this code description is challenging, and IMO, insufficient to determine the segmentation fault.  It would be better for all to see the true code.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a minimal example of your code producing the error.

Comment: You can't use `Replac **replace` like that you only have allocate one `Replac`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c

Answer (score 0):

```
f = fopen( inputfile, "r" );
...
typedef struct 
{
    char utf8[max_UTF];
    char ascii_seq[max_ASCII];
    int count;
} Replac;
...
fgets(data,sizeof data,f);
```

You are mixing binary and text format.

Depending on the compiler, `sizeof(Replac)` will be `16`. This includes `sizeof(int)` which is always `4`. There may also be padding if size is not a multiple of `4`.

If your data is stored as text, then it will be something like this:

```
ABCDE\tABCDEFG123456\n
```

Note that the size of integer in decimal format is anywhere between 0 to 10, so the size is not fixed. And there are (or there should be) new line `\n` characters.

So you don't want to read exactly 16 characters. You want to write and then read 3 lines for each record. Example:

```
ABCDE\n
ABCDEFG\n
123456\n
```

If you are reading in binary, then open the file in binary and use `fwrite` and `fread`. Example:

```
f = fopen( inputfile, "rb" );
Replac data;
fread(f, sizeof(data), 1, f);
```

This all depends on how your file was created. If you are writing the file yourself, then show the code you used for writing the data.

Also, ASCII is a subset of Unicode. `A` in ASCII has the exact same representation as `A` in UTF8.

Comment: I'm not writing anything in the file, the file is simply a utf8char followed by a tab followed by a ascii representation, for  example Ç tab ,C or £ tab pound.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         strcpy(replace[j]->utf8, strtok(data, "\t"));
> ```
>
> I get a segmentation fault after that instruction.

You just got the dereferencing order wrong. You first subscripted with `[j]` and then dereferenced with `->`, as if we had an array of pointers to `Replac`s. But we rather have a pointer to (the first element of) an array of `Replac`s, hence we must dereference the pointer first and subscript thereafter, i. e. instead of

```
                replace[j]->utf8
```

we have to write

```
                (*replace)[j].utf8
```

or the equivalent

```
                (*replace+j)->utf8
```