# Using malloc() for 2d Arrays

Tags: c

I was using malloc() to create a 2d array to store data from the stdin. I wanted to test it out before coding specifically what is required to get a general idea. I found the following code online

```
int r, c;
scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);
int *arr = (int *)malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));
int i, j, count = 0;
for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
      *(arr + i*c + j) = ++count;

for (i = 0; i <  r; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i*c + j));
```

The online code had hardcoded values for r and c so I changed it to a scanf to make it similar to what I would be needing later. It works well but I do not understand why I cannot use arr[i][j] instead of *(arr + i *c +j) in my code. When I tried using it i got the following error:
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

My understanding was that pointers and arrays are interchangeable, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because `arr[i]` is a scalar (you have a 1D array after all), and further indexing on a scalar makes no sense.

Comment: "My understanding was that pointers and arrays are interchangeable, where am I going wrong?" - your understanding is wrong, pointers and arrays are not interchangeable.

Comment: If you use e.g. `arr[i][j]` that assumes that `arr` is either an array of pointers, or an array of arrays. You have a *single* "array". You can however use `arr[i*c + j]`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but [should you really cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)?

Comment: so it is not exactly a 2D array, that makes sense. Thank you guys!

Comment: As for your understanding, an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but it's not a pointer in itself. For example, if you have the definition `int a[10];` then using only `a` when a pointer is expected automatically means `&a[0]`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have an idea for writing a code for a 2D array using malloc, hopefully it will work. Else I will try to overcome my fear of using pointers to reach values

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `arr[i][j]` in this code because `arr` points to type `int` rather than to `int *` or `int[SOME_DIMENSION]`. But if you want to use `malloc` to make a real 2-dimensional array, **you can**:

```
int (*arr)[c] = (int *)malloc(r * sizeof *arr);
```

Now, `arr[i]` has type `int[c]`, which decays to `int *`, and therefore `arr[i][j]` is valid.

Comment: in your code you’re allocating a variable length array, which is not permitted in ISO C, and it is the first reason why `malloc` is used instead.

Comment: @osnapitzkindle maybe read the ISO C standard before making such preposterous statements

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m back to the ISO C90 which is obsolete. Anyway the OP is making a question about the use of `malloc`, and using variable length arrays could make the question without any sense.

Comment: Even if OP were stuck with C89, I think my answer, particularly the C99+ fix for the code, clarifies how the types in the question's snippet were wrong for doing what OP wants and how correct types would make it work. (BTW if `c` happens to be a constant expression rather than a variable you can do this in C89 too.)

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is `int *`, then `arr[i]` is `int`.

`malloc` in that code is creating a **one dimensional** vector long `r*c`.

`*(arr + i*c + j)` can be translated to `arr[i*c + j]`. This means that this vector is divided in `r` segments long `c` and the `i` is selecting the segment, while `j` is the offset in the segment.

You may also use `malloc` to allocate a pointer array, and then `malloc` each pointer of the array. In that case you’d have a `int **` and your method will work, but it’s strongly discouraged cause you’d have to `free` all the pointers in the pointer array.