# Writing to an allocated 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, malloc

I am trying to create a struct with a variable length array of fixed size strings.

```
struct foo_query{
  char tag[10];
  int value_count;
  char * values[VAL_SIZE];
};
```

Now, I want to create an array of these structs, and allocate some memory for the values:

```
#define buffer(a) (char *) malloc(sizeof(char[a][VAL_SIZE]))
foo_query queries[total_queries] = {
    {"FOO", 25, buffer(25)},
    {"BAR", 21, buffer(21)}
};
#undef buffer
```

Finally, I want to actually write some data to the values.

```
query_index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < queries.value_count; i++){
    strncpy(queries[query_index].values[i], "Hello", VAL_SIZE);
    Serial.outln("success");
}
```

But that last bit fails. `success` is printed once or twice, and then everything just stops.

As far as I can tell, the memory has been allocated and I'm not overflowing anything, so why is the code crashing?

Comment: I know similar questions have been asked, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I have done what it says on that question, and my code still does not work.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't ensure the string is NUL terminated

Comment: I'm not sure I see why that's relevant in this case. The problems are occurring on write, not read ( In fact I never read from the array ) so  NULL termination shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: you haven't said on which line the code crashes, so we're left guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: Sorry if it's ambiguous. I'm running on an embedded system, so I'm also guessing what the problem is. It looks like some kind of buffer overflow, because as I said in the question, success is printed once or twice and then everything stops. So I suspect that the buffer allocation that I'm doing is not actually working as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your memory allocating is wrong.

```
foo_query queries[total_queries] = {
    {"FOO", 25, buffer(25)},
    {"BAR", 21, buffer(21)}
};
```

When you create `queries` above, you're only populating the first element of `values` because the way you've defined it, `values` is an array of `char *`.

When you come to put values into that array if `i` is more than 0, you're copying into an unassigned pointer.

```
strncpy(queries[query_index].values[i], "Hello", VAL_SIZE);
```

When `i` is more than 0, `queries[query_index].values[i]` could be NULL or it could be pointing to some part of memory. Either way, it'll lead to undefined behaviour and your code crashing randomly.

Given you're trying to copy `VAL_SIZE` characters into it though, it looks more likely that you've actually defined `values` incorrectly. Rather than an array of `char *`, it looks more likely you're looking for a pointer to a `char` array of `VAL_SIZE`? If that is the case you need to define it as:

```
char (* values)[VAL_SIZE];
```

It would also fit with the rather odd amount of memory you're allocating with `malloc` which would look more clear as `malloc(sizeof(char[VAL_SIZE})*(a))`. (Note: always wrap macro parameters in brackets to ensure you don't have crazy precedence issues ie `buffer(10+10)` turns into `malloc(sizeof(char[VAL_SIZE})*10+10)` without the brackets).

You should still add in

```
queries[query_index].values[i][VAL_SIZE-1]='\0';
```

after the `strncpy` just to make sure that if the string being copied is too large to fit in, that your strings are NUL terminated too.