# C: populate multiple dimension array

Tags: c, arrays

I have several numbers that i want to insert into `Matrix`.

This is how i am get all my numbers one by one:

```
int i, n;
int ch;
int *arr;
int dimension;
int numbers = 0;
char str[512];

// User input.
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i <= (strlen(str)); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != '\0' && !isspace(str[i]))
        {
            int num = atoi(&str[i]);
            numbers++;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                dimension = num;
                arr = allocatearraysize(dimension);
            }

            // Here i want to add the current number to my `Maxtix`.
        }
    }

free(arr);

int* allocatearraysize(int size)
{
    return (int *)malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));
}
```

So i try:

```
arr[0][0] = num;
```

only for see if thats works but got an `error`:

> expression must have pointer-to-object type

**Edit**

So if my input is `2 1 2 3 4`:

the first `number` (`2`) means that my `matrix` should be `2x2` and i expected 4 `numbers` after this `number` (`2`).

In case the `numbers` of `number` not match the first `number` for example:

```
3 1 2 3 4
```

The first `number` here is 3 so after this `number` i excepted to `9` `numbers` so in this case i only want to print `error` message.

But any way i want to insert this `numbers` into my `Matrix`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `num = atoi(str[i])`?

Comment: @GokulanRavi No it should not

Comment: `atoi` expects a `char *` as parameter, not a char. You have to put just `atoi(str)`. Please read the manual of a function before using it

Comment: This code has quite a lot of problems, starting with the fact  you are iterating over each character of an input string but it looks like you want to just read the string into an int.

Comment: Thats right, i only want int

Comment: arr points to a 1-d array. For the (i, j) element you should write `arr[i * row_size + j]`, where `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index. Otherwise use a double pointer

Comment: What is the input you are giving ? If you give 3 1 2 3, then it will create a 1D array of 3*3 ie. of size 9. But your for loop is running only 4 times ?

Comment: for example 2 1 2 3 4, the first number (2) means that this matrix will be 2x2 so after the number 2 i need another 4 numbers

Comment: Are you sure you want a Matrix (like arr[20][100]) or do you want a dynamic array (like arr[99]) where the size (99) is dynamic? (Which you control with malloc)...

Comment: If the number of numbers after the first number (which is the array dimension) is wrong i just print error message.

Comment: Please edit your question with extra clarification....What inputs you use, and what outputs you expect

Comment: Please see  my edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  For a start, shouldn't you define your Matrix (2-dimensional array) as int **arr;   ?  Which means alot of small changes to your code

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You use the word Matrix, which is a multi dimensional array (usually).  You are only declaring a single dimensional array with int *arr;  Perhaps you want to research Matrices in C first...Google for an example

Comment: See here perhaps for a few examples, not sure which one you are wishing to use... http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Comment: @Grantly Geeks for geeks is a trash site. Sure, they show the correct way to do this in C90 (1st example), but they don't show the correct way to do this in standard C. Please don't link to external trash sites written by students, when we have SO that contains much higher quality posts written by domain experts.

Comment: @Lundin LOL yes I didn't spend much time finding an example for the OP...I didn't realise it was trash - just thought the 3/4 examples were worthwhile for the OP to look at...  Yes I overlooked some SO examples as they seemed too complex for the OP at the moment.  Please add a better link if you have time.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Grantly I already closed this as a duplicate, you can follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). Sure, I am partial since I wrote that post, though if you look at [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c) you find the same kind of recommendations posted by domain experts, C programming book authors and members of the C standard committee.

Comment: @Lundin Awesome, thanks. (Upvoted too)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access arrays with `var[i][j]` if it's not  a 2-dimensional array.

A possible answer would be :

```
int i, j, n;
int ch;
int **arr;
int size;
int numbers = 0;
char str[512];

fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

size = atoi(&str[0]);

if(size > 1) {
    arr = (int**) malloc(size * sizeof(int*))

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    // Fill with arr[i][j]

    free(arr);
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Size must be a valid number");
}
```

Comment: This is not a 2-dimension array either, yet you can access elements through `[x][y]`. Your answer contradicts itself.

Comment: @Lundin do you say that because he is actually using a pointer to a pointer?  (Which is not strictly a 2D array)?  I'm just thinking that this dynamic allocation makes it clear to the OP - even though its not exactly accurate...

Comment: @Grantly Yes, this is not a 2D array, it is a form of lookup table. It is significantly slower than a dynamically allocated 2D array. In addition, it is more dangerous and error prone. In this case there is no need to use a pointer-based lookup table. Do not write slow and dangerous code when you can write fast and safe code to achieve the very same thing.

Comment: @Lundin forget about stricts explanations, obviously it's a mind representation. I'm just giving a simple solution to this problem. I don't think OP is looking for the fastest, strictest code

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, yeah I hear you :)  Be good to see your alternative in code, but I don't want to ask you to detail it here...  Its a good exercise for the OP to navigate the alternatives

Comment: How exactly is this code simpler than `int (*arr)[size] = malloc( sizeof[size][size] );` ... `free(arr);`? Ignoring the fact that your answer contains a major memory leak bug when you free() the allocated