# What is the best way to declare and initialize a 2D array dynamically allocated?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I tried in this way, but I don't know if it's the best way to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 5
#define COL 5

int *matrix;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    matrix = malloc(ROW * COL * sizeof(int));
    memset(matrix, 0, ROW * COL * sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be more specific about what you're worried your solution might be "not best" in.

Comment: I got the doubt because I have seen some solutions in which each column is allocated with malloc and initialized with memset (in a for loop).

Comment: @link23 If the array has equal size in all dimensions, you might as well allocate a one-dimensional array and do some simple math getting the right index.

Comment: @Cheatah: 1. OP is already doing this. 2. This holds even if the sizes in different dimensions are not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c)

Comment: @einpoklum they are, but they seem to be in doubt. And it does not hold if the sizes in the different dimensions differ, because you would need to know the largest edge size. I think the code is fine, but ideally it should read `matrix = calloc(ROW * COL, *matrix);`

Answer (score 0):

(I'm ignoring the word "best" in your question title)

1. Try to [avoid global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad). If you need `matrix` in `main()`, then declare it in `main()` and pass it to other functions as necessary.
2. As @Vlad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452029/1593077) mentions - if you specifically want to set your array to zero, you can combine your `malloc()` and `memset()` calls into a single `calloc()` ("clear-allocate" if you will) call.
3. If you know the matrix dimensions in advance, you might just allocate the matrix on the stack, e.g.:

   ```
   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   {
       int matrix[ROW * COL] = { 0 };
       // etc. etc.
   }
   ```

   (which should set the whole array to zero as well.)

   if, on the other hand, the matrix is quite large, then even for dimensions known apriori it makes more sense to allocate dynamically, because stack space is limited.
4. It is *not* a good idea to allocate every column or every row separately with `malloc()`. Even if you wanted your matrix to be used in the form `matrix[i][j]`, you would still use a single allocation - but allocate space for the actual data as well as a sequence of pointers to column beginnings.

Further reading:

- [How do I correctly set up, access, and free a multidimensional array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462615/how-do-i-correctly-set-up-access-and-free-a-multidimensional-array-in-c)
- [comp.lang.c FAQ 6.16:  How can I dynamically allocate a multidimensional array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Comment: Does the expression matrix[ROW * COL] is equal to matrix[ROW][COL]? Furthermore, in this case can't I just write matrix[ROW * COL] = {0};?

Comment: @link23: That's a good question. It is _mostly_ equivalent, in the sense that you would get the same memory layout. I didn't recommend it because when you pass such a "pseudo-2D-C-matrix" around, you either pass it as a plain `int*` or you have to include the `COL` parameter in every function's signature. Also, for listing code, use backticks (`).

Comment: @link23 in this case `matrix2d[x][y]` would be equivalent to either `matrix1d[x * ROW + y]` or `matrix1d[x + y * COL];` as long as you are consistent and always use either the one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to deal with a matrix when it is represented as a two-dimensional array.

Instead of calling `malloc` and then `memset` manually you can substitute them for a call of `calloc`.

So you can write in main (there is no need to declare the pointer in the file scope)

```
int ( *matrix )[COL] = calloc( 1, sizeof( int[ROW][COL] ) );
```

Using such an array makes code more clear. For example to output the matrix you can write

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < ROW; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < COL; j++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", matrix[i][j] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

To conclude about difficulties of using a one-dimensional array imagine how will look a code of multiplication of two matrices.