# How to allocate dynamically-sized 2d array using only one malloc with double-square-brackets (arr[i][j]) access syntax in C?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamically-sized-type

Have C classes in university, but now hours of googling haven't answered my question.

I know that there are compiled-time arrays in C like:

```
#define N 2
#define M 3

int array[N][M] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                    { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

This array:

1. Allocated in memory uniformly: like

```
-------------
|1|2|3|4|5|6|
-------------
```

2. I can access it by simple:

```
arr[i][j]
```

But if I want to have similar array but dynamically sized?

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462760/8463690), which suggests:

```
int main() {
  int N, M;
  scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

  int (*arr)[N] = malloc(sizeof(int[N][M]));

  return 0;
}
```

This looks like what I search for, but my Visual Studio refuses to compile it:

```
1>C:\Users\Name\VisualStudioProjects\lab2\lab2\lab51.c(18,26): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>C:\Users\Name\VisualStudioProjects\lab2\lab2\lab51.c(18,27): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

I've tried to set Project -> Properties -> General -> C Language Standard to "ISO C11 Standard", but this didn't help.

Could you hint me the proper way to achieve what I want in C?
Namely:

1. 2d array
2. Dynamically allocated using non-constant sizes
3. Using only one `malloc()` instead of `1 + N`
4. Having access syntax as `arr[i][j]`

And is it feasible at all?

Comment: Variable length arrays are an optional language feature, and MSVC doesn't implement it.

Comment: I'd suggest a two malloc() call approach. The first being for an "index array" as in the 1 of the 1+N approach, the second being an N * M sized array with the entries of the index array set to point to the appropriate places inside the N * M "body" array. Not as neat as the style you found, but will work with MSVC and doesn't require dealing with the issues involved in combining those 2 allocations into one.

Comment: @AviBerger: That is a bad method because it has undesired performance effects (chained pointer lookups break processor preloading since it cannot do the chained load without getting the first result from memory) merely for an deceptive aesthetic look. It should not be recommended to people learning C.

Comment: You are out of luck as your compiler does not support VLAs

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does have the undesired performance effects, but as far as I know that is unavoidable if the VLA style approach is not supported and the access syntax of arr[i][j] remains a requirement. Without that access syntax requirement, one could do the stride calculations oneself and avoid the performance issues. Either one could be a challenge to someone learning C. which is better for a beginner, I'd consider a toss up.

Comment: @AviBerger: Do the stride calculations oneself. Using the `arr[i][j]` syntax is not a requirement in a reasonable project. If there is some bad project manager out there demanding it, leave that to them. It is not a reason to recommend it to students now. Do not send students down a bad path.

Comment: The answer reads: 'In C since C99' Well apparently Visual Studio compiler is not conforming C99.

Comment: @Name EricPostpischil is correct about the undesired performance effects of my suggestion. Learning to do the stride calculations yourself is a good thing and is the only way I know of to avoid those effects with a compiler like MSVC that does not support the method you showed. It does work with 1 malloc, but does not provide the arr[i][j] access syntax.

Comment: That is correct, @CPlus, Microsoft's C compiler does not conform to C99, and never did, even when that was the current standard.  This is not the only deviation.  It complies with C11 and C17 in this particular regard, I think, because C11 made VLA support optional, although I'm assuming without checking this Microsoft C makes the appropriate feature-test macro definitions for omitting VLA support.  Microsoft has long favored C++, and seems to have little enthusiasm for the aspects of C that differentiate it from C++, such as VLAs.

Comment: @CPlus [It's not exactly a secret](https://www.google.com/search?q=msvc+not+c99+compliant+site:stackoverflow.com) that, with the 21st century already one quarter over, MSVC *still* doesn't support last century's C standard...

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is why personally, for me, I just use GCC/Clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you hint me the proper way to achieve what I want in C? Namely:
>
> ```
>  1. 2d array
>  2. Dynamically allocated using non-constant sizes
>  3. Using only one malloc() instead of 1 + N
>  4. Having access syntax as arr[i][j]
> ```

Unfortunatelly you are out of luck as you use MS compiler which does not support VLAs. You need workarounds.

1. Only as an array of pointers or single dimension array and macros or functions to access the elements
2. Same as p. 1
3. Only as 1D array
4. Only as an array of pointers.